# Using deprecated binders and C++0x lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, bind, traits

C++0x has deprecated the use of old binders such as `bind1st` and `bind2nd` in favor of generic `std::bind`. C++0x lambdas bind nicely with `std::bind` but they don't bind with classic bind1st and bind2nd because by default lambdas don't have nested typedefs such as `argument_type`, `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type`, and `result_type`. 
So I thought `std::function` can serve as a standard way to bind lambdas to the old binders because it exposes the necessary typedefs.

However, using `std::function` is hard to use in this context because it forces you to spell out the function-type while instantiating it.

```
auto bound = 
  std::bind1st(std::function<int (int, int)>([](int i, int j){ return i < j; }), 10); // hard to use
auto bound = 
  std::bind1st(std::make_function([](int i, int j){ return i < j; }), 10); // nice to have but does not compile.
```

I could not find a convenient object generator for `std::function`. Something like `std::make_fuction` would be nice to have. Does such a thing exist? If not, is there any other better way of binding lamdas to the classic binders?

Comment: Note that using classic binders with lambdas might be useful for legacy libraries that expect their function object types to expose the above mentioned typedefs. So I don't think vanilla lambdas can be used with such libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never tried to do such thing, and I don't have the time to provide a full answer, but I guess that something could be done with Boost.FunctionTypes.

Here's a rough, incomplete and untested draft to give you an idea:

```
template <typename T>
struct AdaptedAsUnary : T
{
    namespace bft = boost::function_types;
    namespace bmpl = boost::mpl;

    typedef typename bft::result_type<T>::type result_type;
    typedef typename bmpl::front<typename bft::parameter_types<T>::type>::type argument_type;

    AdaptedAsUnary(T t) : T(t) {}
};

template <typename T>
AdaptedAsUnary<T>
AdaptAsUnary(T t)
{
    return AdaptedAsUnary<T>(t);
}
```

Comment: This is a neat solution. Inheriting from a lambda-type is new to me and works nicely on g++ 4.5. Although as of today, boost::function_types (1.42) does not support lambdas as a built-in callable type, I could find my way out. In future, when they support it (I hope), this solution can be used as is. For now, I used the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562320/specializing-a-template-on-a-lambda-in-c0x as a substitute for the introspection capabilities of boost::function_types. Using those function_traits for lambdas, multiple inheritance from T and std::unary_function works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you still need the bind1st etc. The only thing I could think of is to support old code. Actually, `bind1st(f, a)` can be replaced by `[a](v){ return f(a, v); }` etc, and this is a universal solution.