# lambda traits inconsistency across C++0x compilers

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, traits

I observed some inconsistency between two compilers (g++ 4.5, VS2010 RC) in the way they match lambdas with partial specializations of class templates. I was trying to implement something like boost::function_types for lambdas to extract type traits. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562320/specializing-a-template-on-a-lambda-in-c0x) for more details.

In g++ 4.5, the type of the `operator()` of a lambda appears to be like that of a free standing function (R (*)(...)) whereas in VS2010 RC, it appears to be like that of a member function (R (C::*)(...)). So the question is are compiler writers free to interpret any way they want? If not, which compiler is correct? See the details below.

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits 
  : function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> 
{ 
// This generic template is instantiated on both the compilers as expected.
};

template <typename R, typename C>
struct function_traits<R (C::*)() const>  { // inherits from this one on VS2010 RC
  typedef R result_type;
};

template <typename R>
struct function_traits<R (*)()> { // inherits from this one on g++ 4.5
  typedef R result_type;
};

int main(void) {
  auto lambda = []{};
  function_traits<decltype(lambda)>::result_type *r; // void *
}
```

This program compiles on both g++ 4.5 and VS2010 but the function_traits that are instantiated are different as noted in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I believe that GCC is noncompliant.</s> N3092 §5.1.2/5 says

> The closure type for a
>   lambda-expression has a public inline
>   function call operator (13.5.4) whose
>   param- eters and return type are
>   described by the lambda-expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause and
>   trailing- return-type respectively.
>   This function call operator is
>   declared const (9.3.1) if and only if
>   the lambda- expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause is not
>   followed by mutable.

So while many things about the closure object's type are implementation-defined, the function itself must be a member to be `public` and must be a nonstatic member to be `const`.

**EDIT:** This program indicates that `operator()` is a member function on GCC 4.6, which is essentially the same as 4.5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template< class ... > struct print_types {};

template<> struct print_types<> {
 friend ostream &operator<< ( ostream &lhs, print_types const &rhs ) {
  return lhs;
 }
};

template< class H, class ... T > struct print_types<H, T...> {
 friend ostream &operator<< ( ostream &lhs, print_types const &rhs ) {
  lhs << typeid(H).name() << " " << print_types<T...>();
  return lhs;
 }
};

template< class T >
struct spectfun {
 friend ostream &operator<< ( ostream &lhs, spectfun const &rhs ) {
  lhs << "unknown";
  return lhs;
 }
};

template< class R, class ... A >
struct spectfun< R (*)( A ... ) > {
 friend ostream &operator<< ( ostream &lhs, spectfun const &rhs ) {
  lhs << "returns " << print_types<R>()
   << " takes " << print_types<A ...>();
  return lhs;
 }
};

template< class C, class R, class ... A >
struct spectfun< R (C::*)( A ... ) > {
 friend ostream &operator<< ( ostream &lhs, spectfun const &rhs ) {
  lhs << "member of " << print_types<C>() << ", " << spectfun<R (*)(A...)>();
  return lhs;
 }
};

template< class T >
struct getcall {
 typedef decltype(&T::operator()) type;
};

int main() {
 int counter = 0;

 auto count = [=]( int ) mutable { return ++ counter; };

 cerr << spectfun< getcall<decltype(count)>::type >() << endl;
}
```

output:

```
member of Z4mainEUlvE_, returns i takes i
```

**EDIT:** It looks like the only problem is that pointers to certain closure call operators fail to match ptmf template patterns. The workaround is to declare the lambda expression `mutable`. This is meaningless if there is no capture and only (aside from fixing the problem) seems to change the const-ness of the call operator.

```
template< class T >
struct getcall {
    typedef decltype(&T::operator()) type;
    static type const value;
};
template< class T >
typename getcall<T>::type const getcall<T>::value = &T::operator();

int main() {
    auto id = []( int x ) mutable { return x; };
    int (*idp)( int ) = id;
    typedef decltype(id) idt;
    int (idt::*idptmf)( int ) /* const */ = getcall< decltype(id) >::value;

cerr << spectfun< decltype(idp) >() << endl;
cerr << spectfun< decltype(idptmf) >() << endl;
cerr << spectfun< getcall<decltype(id)>::type >() << endl;
```

output:

```
returns i takes i 
member of Z4mainEUliE0_ , returns i takes i 
member of Z4mainEUliE0_ , returns i takes i
```

Without the mutable and with the const, `spectfun` does not print signatures for either of the last two queries.

Comment: Wouldn't that make g++ noncompliant, since it uses free-functions?

Comment: @Gman, jalf: Bah, selective hearing. Well, GCC's method involves more friendship… ha!

Comment: Heh. Well, could it be the case that GCC is making the function static? I think I'm obviously incorrect in stating it's a free function, as a free function has no `T::operator()`. I sadly don't have g++ 4.5 on me to test with. Perhaps making the lambda mutable would force the function to be non-static, because the lambda would carry data.

Comment: @GMan: I'm trying to tease some information out of 4.6. It does correctly implement `mutable` but it looks somewhat like the lambda itself is a function-class, analogous to the class implicitly defined for the function it's within.

Comment: g++ 4.5 makes any lambda with a capture into expected R (C::*)(...) type. Capture-less lambdas don't appear to behave like that. Although we know based on n3043 (see below) that stateless lambdas are convertible to function pointers, when a better match R(C::*)(...) is present, it should be chosen I think. In that respect g++ is not compliant because it neglects a better match but rightly implements a conversion to R(*)(...). Am I right?

Comment: @Sumant: Aha, I didn't try one like that! You're right, this program succeeds in extracting `decltype(…::operator())` but doesn't match it to any function type. I'll look into more later.

Comment: @Sumant: Can you work around the problem entirely by declaring the lambdas `mutable`?

Comment: @Potatocom: g++ complains saying that capture-less lambdas can't be mutable. BTW, I'm doing this exercise for educational purpose.

Comment: @Sumant: Mine doesn't, it was updated on April 7. I have no real interest either. Maybe we both should update, lol. Support is much better than it was and nearly complete, which is good to know at least.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Updated g++ 4.5 seems to work as expected. decltype(&T::operator()) matches R(C::*)(...) and stateless lambdas are convertible to R(*)(...).

Answer (score 1):

Read [n3043](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3043.html). Lambdas are now convertible to function pointers provided they don't have any state. I believe (...but do not know) GCC initially implemented this behavior accidentally, "fixed it", now will be re-adding it to 4.5 or 4.6. VC10 implemented lambdas correctly as initially designed, but not conforming to the latest working papers with n3043.

Comment: n3092 is the latest draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf [PDF link]

Comment: Yes, it is - but I'm talking about n3043 specifically.

Comment: Even though stateless lambdas are convertible to function pointers, when a better match R(C::*)(...) is present, it should be chosen, isn't it?

Comment: @Sumant, @Terry: I don't have 3043 but 3096 specifies "a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function". This is similar to but incompatible with altering the type of the closure object itself. The standard essentially requires *both* a function pointer and a ptmf be available for the call operator. Both are available under GCC but the ptmf does not appear to match templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think gcc developers has a good reason for this behaivor. Remember, a static function do not have a "this" pointer, and when it is being actually called, the caller do not required to pass the "this" pointer. So this is a small performance optimisation when it is actually nothing contained in the closure object. And you can see the G++ developer leave you a way to workaround by declaring the lambda expression as "mutable" (remember you actually do not have anything to mutate).