# trait to drop const from a member function type?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

When `T` is `double(float)const` I get this error when I try to use `function<T>`.

```
implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::function<double (float) const>'
```

But it's OK when `T` is `double(float)`. I tried to use `std:: remove_cv<T>::type` to remove this `const`, but that doesn't work. And yes, I have `#include<functional>`.

So my main question is: How to fix this and remove `const` so that I can put this function type into `std:: function`.?

---

I came across this issue when working with the `operator()` method of lambdas, but I think this question is generally about any method type, not just for lambdas

---

But my second question is: What does `double(float)const` even mean ?!! I can understand

```
double (ClassName::) (float) const
```

as it means the member function cannot modify its `ClassName` object. When I put this type into a template to remove the class type, then I get the `double(float)const` which is causing trouble.

```
template<typename>
struct DropClassType;
template<typename Sig, typename C>
struct DropClassType<Sig (C::*)> {
  typedef Sig type_without_class;
};
```

(clang 3.4.2. The errors from g++-4.9.1 are more cryptic, but basically the same)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why did I get the "implicit instantiation of undefined template" error?

`std::function` is defined as an undefined base template and a partial specialization that matches "normal" function types (§20.9.11.2 [func.wrap.func]):

```
template<class> class function; // undefined
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class function<R(ArgTypes...)>  { /* ... */ };
```

`double (float) const` doesn't match `R(ArgTypes...)`, so you get the undefined base template instead.

---

> How to fix this and remove const so that I can put this function type into `std::function`?

The standard partial specialization trick. While we are at it, let's also remove `volatile`.

```
template<class> class rm_func_cv; // undefined
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class rm_func_cv<R(ArgTypes...)>  { using type = R(ArgTypes...); };
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class rm_func_cv<R(ArgTypes...) const>  { using type = R(ArgTypes...); };
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class rm_func_cv<R(ArgTypes...) volatile>  { using type = R(ArgTypes...); };
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class rm_func_cv<R(ArgTypes...) const volatile>  { using type = R(ArgTypes...); };
```

Similar tricks can be used to remove *ref-qualifiers*, of course.

---

> What does `double (float) const` even mean ?!!

This is a rather obscure corner of the standard (§8.3.5 [dcl.fct]/p6):

> A function type with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier* (including
>   a type named by *typedef-name* (7.1.3, 14.1)) shall appear only as:
>
> - the function type for a non-static member function,
> - the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or alias-declaration,
> - the *type-id* in the default argument of a *type-parameter* (14.1), or
> - the *type-id* of a *template-argument* for a *type-parameter* (14.3.1).
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
>     typedef int FIC(int) const;
>     FIC f; // ill-formed: does not declare a member function
>     struct S {
>       FIC f; // OK
>     };
>     FIC S::*pm = &S::f; // OK
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

In short, it's basically "half a type" that you can use to declare a class member function or a pointer-to-member type (or pass as a template parameter).

Comment: Cool. So it doesn't really mean anything "on its own", but it can make sense again when reassociated with a class as in the two examples you gave. Is there a standard trait to remove the const?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I'm not aware of any. It's obscure enough that I doubt anyone thought of writing a trait for it.

Comment: I think this will be less obscure in future thanks to lambdas. This has allowed me to write a function which will take any (non-generic) lambda, or similar object, and automatically convert it to a `std:: function` object. Simply running `decltype(&T::operator())` on a lambda will return a type, but it's necessary to remove the class type, and this strange `const`, from that type. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct function_remove_const;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_remove_const<R(Args...)>
{
    using type = R(Args...);
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_remove_const<R(Args...)const>
{
    using type = R(Args...);
};

int main()
{
    std::function<function_remove_const<double(float)const>::type> f;
}
```

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/1ugsSF)