# What matches a cv-qualified non-member function type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++

Looking at the GNU g++ 4.8.4 `type_traits` header code I've found the definition for the `std::is_function` template. It includes some template specializations such as this:

```
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
  struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...) const>
   : public true_type { };
```

Specializations for `volatile` and `const volatile` functions are also there.

It is known that only member functions can be declared cv-qualified. So what do these specializations match? Is this a GNU extension?

Comment: They are essentially "half a type". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654186/trait-to-drop-const-from-a-member-function-type/25654229#25654229

Comment: Thanks @T.C. ! Would you like elaborate a answer for this question?