# How do we use void_t for SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I watched Walter Brown's talk at Cppcon14 about modern template programming ([Part I](http://youtu.be/Am2is2QCvxY), [Part II](http://youtu.be/a0FliKwcwXE)) where he presented his `void_t` SFINAE technique.

Example:
Given a simple variable template that evaluates to `void` if all template arguments are well formed:

```
template< class ... > using void_t = void;
```

and the following trait that checks for the existence of a data member called *member*:

```
template< class , class = void >
struct has_member : std::false_type
{ };

// specialized as has_member< T , void > or discarded (SFINAE)
template< class T >
struct has_member< T , void_t< decltype( T::member ) > > : std::true_type
{ };
```

I tried to understand why and how this works. Therefore a tiny example:

```
class A {
public:
    int member;
};

class B {
};

static_assert( has_member< A >::value , "A" );
static_assert( has_member< B >::value , "B" );
```

**1.** `has_member< A >`

- `has_member< A , void_t< decltype( A::member ) > >`

  - `A::member` exists
  - `decltype( A::member )` is well-formed
  - `void_t<>` is valid and evaluates to `void`
- `has_member< A , void >` and therefore it chooses the specialized template
- `has_member< T , void >` and evaluates to `true_type`

**2.** `has_member< B >`

- `has_member< B , void_t< decltype( B::member ) > >`

  - `B::member` does not exist
  - `decltype( B::member )` is ill-formed and fails silently (sfinae)
  - `has_member< B , expression-sfinae >` so this template is discarded
- compiler finds `has_member< B , class = void >` with void as default argument
- `has_member< B >` evaluates to `false_type`

http://ideone.com/HCTlBb

Questions:

1. Is my understanding of this correct?
2. Walter Brown states that the default argument has to be the exact same type as the one used in `void_t` for it to work. Why is that? (I don't see why this types need to match, doesn't just any default type does the job?)

Comment: Ad 2) Imagine the static assert was written as: `has_member<A,int>::value`. Then, the partial specialization that evaluates to `has_member<A,void>` cannot match. Therefore, it needs to be `has_member<A,void>::value`, or, with syntactic sugar, a default argument of type `void`.

Comment: @dyp Thanks, I'll edit that. Mh, I do not see a need in having `has_member< T , class = void >` defaulting in `void` yet. Assuming this trait will be used only with 1 template argument at any time, then the default argument could be any type?

Comment: Note that In this proposal, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf, Walter changed `template <class, class = void>` to `template <class, class = void_t<>>`.  So now we are free to do whatever we want with `void_t` alias template implementation :)

Comment: stupid question: how can you access ::value when it is not declared / defined? The inheritance from 'std::false_type' is a boolean. So why can ::value be a string?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

## 1. Primary Class Template

When you write `has_member<A>::value`, the compiler looks up the name `has_member` and finds the *primary* class template, that is, this declaration:

```
template< class , class = void >
struct has_member;
```

(In the OP, that's written as a definition.)

The template argument list `<A>` is compared to the template parameter list of this primary template. Since the primary template has two parameters, but you only supplied one, the remaining parameter is defaulted to the default template argument: `void`. It's as if you had written `has_member<A, void>::value`.

## 2. Specialized Class Template

**Now**, the template parameter list is compared against any specializations of the template `has_member`. Only if no specialization matches, the definition of the primary template is used as a fall-back. So the partial specialization is taken into account:

```
template< class T >
struct has_member< T , void_t< decltype( T::member ) > > : true_type
{ };
```

The compiler tries to match the template arguments `A, void` with the patterns defined in the partial specialization: `T` and `void_t<..>` one by one. ***First***, template argument deduction is performed. The partial specialization above is still a template with template-parameters that need to be "filled" by arguments.

**The first pattern** `T`, allows the compiler to deduce the template-parameter `T`. This is a trivial deduction, but consider a pattern like `T const&`, where we could still deduce `T`. For the pattern `T` and the template argument `A`, we deduce `T` to be `A`.

**In the second pattern** `void_t< decltype( T::member ) >`, the template-parameter `T` appears in a context where it cannot be deduced from any template argument.

> There are two reasons for this:
>
> - The expression inside `decltype` is explicitly excluded from template argument deduction. I guess this is because it can be arbitrarily complex.
> - Even if we used a pattern without `decltype` like `void_t< T >`, then the deduction of `T` happens on the resolved alias template. That is, we resolve the alias template and later try to deduce the type `T` from the resulting pattern. The resulting pattern, however, is `void`, which is not dependent on `T` and therefore does not allow us to find a specific type for `T`. This is similar to the mathematical problem of trying to invert a constant function (in the mathematical sense of those terms).

Template argument deduction is finished<sup>(*)</sup>, ***now*** the *deduced* template arguments are substituted. This creates a specialization that looks like this:

```
template<>
struct has_member< A, void_t< decltype( A::member ) > > : true_type
{ };
```

The type `void_t< decltype( A::member ) >` can now be evaluated. It is well-formed after substitution, hence, no *Substitution Failure* occurs. We get:

```
template<>
struct has_member<A, void> : true_type
{ };
```

## 3. Choice

**Now**, we can compare the template parameter list of this specialization with the template arguments supplied to the original `has_member<A>::value`. Both types match exactly, so this partial specialization is chosen.

---

On the other hand, when we define the template as:

```
template< class , class = int > // <-- int here instead of void
struct has_member : false_type
{ };

template< class T >
struct has_member< T , void_t< decltype( T::member ) > > : true_type
{ };
```

We end up with the same specialization:

```
template<>
struct has_member<A, void> : true_type
{ };
```

but our template argument list for `has_member<A>::value` now is `<A, int>`. The arguments do not match the parameters of the specialization, and the primary template is chosen as a fall-back.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The Standard, IMHO confusingly, includes the substitution process and the matching of explicitly specified template arguments in the *template argument deduction* process. For example (post-N4296) [temp.class.spec.match]/2:

> A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list
>   if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced
>   from the actual template argument list.

But this does not *just* mean that all template-parameters of the partial specialization have to be deduced; it also means that substitution must succeed and (as it seems?) the template arguments have to match the (substituted) template parameters of the partial specialization. Note that I'm not completely aware of *where* the Standard specifies the comparison between the substituted argument list and the supplied argument list.

Comment: I cannot even find in which step the Standard inserts the default template-arguments of the primary (class) template into the template argument list supplied to the partial specialization :(

Comment: Thank you! I've read it over and over again, and I guess my thinking of how template argument deduction exactly works and what the compiler chooses for the final template is at the moment not correct.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks! That's a bit depressing, though. Are there really no rules for matching a template argument with a specialization? Not even for explicit specializations?

Comment: @dyp for explicit specializations, there is no argument deduction involved and stuff is much simplier. As far as I can remember, the necessary text for matching to explicit specializations is present (and is a few words), but don't quote me on that :) Has been some time since I last looked into the spec for anything.

Comment: These phrases seem to be sufficient to describe explicit specializations: 14.4p1, and the "Unless a ..." rules in 14.7.1p1..p5. The matching is implicit by 3.8 and 14.4p1.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Thanks again. How is 3.8 "Object lifetime" related to matching of template argument lists?

Comment: @dyp sorry for the confusion. I meant 3p8.

Comment: W/r/t default template arguments, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2008

Comment: @dyp A few weeks later and reading alot about this and with a hint from [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/jefftrull/ff6083e2e92fdabb62f6) i think i begin to understand how this works. Your explanation makes from read to read more sense to me, thanks!

Comment: I wanted to add, that the term **primary** template was the key (the templates first encounter in the code)

Comment: @dyp. Thanks for your answer. But I didn't understand this sentence. "  In the second pattern, the template-parameter appears in a non-deduced context. Hence, we cannot deduce the template parameter T from the second template argument void." could you please clarify this ?

Comment: @praveen I've tried to elaborate that section a bit, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 22):

```
// specialized as has_member< T , void > or discarded (sfinae)
template<class T>
struct has_member<T , void_t<decltype(T::member)>> : true_type
{ };
```

That above specialization exists only when it is well formed, so when `decltype( T::member )` is valid and not ambiguous.
the specialization is so for `has_member<T , void>` as state in the comment.

When you write `has_member<A>`, it is `has_member<A, void>` because of default template argument.

And we have specialization for `has_member<A, void>` (so inherit from `true_type`) but we don't have specialization for `has_member<B, void>` (so we use the default definition : inherit from `false_type`)

Comment: So `void_t<decltype(T::member)>>` is nothing more than a standardized/clearer way of writing `decltype(T::member, void())`?

Comment: @303: some (old) compiler version had difficulty to apply SFINAE with (some implementations of) `void_t` though.

Answer (score 2):

This thread and the thread [SFINAE: Understanding void_t and detect_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276542/sfinae-understanding-void-t-and-detect-if) saved me. I want to demonstrate the behavior by some examples:

The tool: [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/)

To test the implmentation by types of float and following types:

```cpp
struct A {
    using type = int;
};

struct B{
    using type = void;
}
```

Tested by

```cpp
auto f = has_type_member<float>::value;
auto a = has_type_member<A>::value;
auto b = has_type_member<B>::value;
```

### standard implmentataion

From [this std::void_t reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// primary template handles types that have no nested ::type member:
template< class, class = int >
struct has_type_member : std::false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a nested ::type member:
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>> : std::true_type { };
```

Output

```cpp
bool f = false;
bool a = true;
bool b = true;

bool x = has_type_member<A, int>::value; //x = false;
```

### case 1

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// primary template handles types that have no nested ::type member:
template< class, class = int >
struct has_type_member : std::false_type { };

template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, void> : std::true_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a nested ::type member:
template< class T >
struct has_type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>> : std::true_type { };
```

Output

```sh
/home/insights/insights.cpp:14:8: error: redefinition of 'has_type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>>'
struct has_type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>> : std::true_type { };
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/insights/insights.cpp:8:8: note: previous definition is here
struct has_type_member<T, void>: std::true_type {};
       ^
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/insights/insights.cpp.
```

So, `has_type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>>`  defined a specialization of `has_type_member` and the signature is exactly `has_type_member<T, void>`.

### case 2

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template< class, class = void >
struct has_type_member : std::false_type { };

// specialize 2nd type as void
template< class T>
struct has_type_member<T, void> : std::true_type { };
```

Output:

```cpp
bool f = true;
bool a = true;
bool b = true;
```

This case shows that the compiler:

1. Wanted to find a match for `has_type_member<float>`
2. Found out that the template requires 2 arguments, then filled the 2nd argument by default arguments. The struct was like `has_type_member<float, void>`
3. Found a specialization of this signature and got the value from `std::true_type`

#### case 3

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template< class, class = void >
struct has_type_member : std::false_type { };

template<class T>
struct has_type_member<T, typename T::type>: std::true_type {};
```

Output:

```cpp
bool f = false;
bool a = false;
bool b = true;
```

##### case f

1. `has_type_member<float>` was completed into `has_type_member<float, void>`.
2. Then the compiler tried `typename float::type` and failed.
3. The primary template picked.

##### case a

1. `has_type_member<A>` was completed into `has_type_member<A, void>`
2. Then compiler tried `has_type_member<A, typename A::type>` and found out it was `has_type_member<A, int>`
3. Compiler decided it was not a specilization of `has_type_member<A, void>`
4. Then primary template picked.

##### case b

1. `has_type_member<B>` was completed into `has_type_member<B, void>`.
2. Then compiler tried `has_type_member<B, typename B::type>` and found out it was `has_type_member<B, void>`.
3. Compiler decided it was a specilization of `has_type_member<B, void>`
4. `true_type` picked.

#### case 4

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

//int as default 2nd argument
template< class, class = int >
struct has_type_member : std::false_type { };

template<class T>
struct has_type_member<T, std::void<typename T::type>>: std::true_type {};
```

Output:

```cpp
bool f = false;
bool a = false;
bool b = false;
```

The `has_type_member<T>` is of type `has_type_member<T, int>` for all 3 variables, while the `true_type` has signature as `has_type_member<T, void>` if it's valid.

#### Conclusion

So, the `std::void_t`:

1. Check if `T::type` valid.
2. Provides a specialization of primary template if only one template argument provided.

Comment: what is `std::void`?