# void_t spezialization why does primary template has to have default = void?

Tags: c++, sfinae, tmp

i've got a question about the void_t metafunction, shown in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE and the question asked at 41:25.

I'll try to show my question with this code snippet:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up, typename = void>
class __is_assignable_helper_af2: public std::false_type
{
};


template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
class __is_assignable_helper_af2<_Tp, _Up,
     void_t<decltype(std::declval<_Tp&>() = std::declval<_Up&>())>> 
  : public std::true_type
{
};
```

Why does the first template need the default type void ?
int doesn't work.

What I understand is that both functions will have the same signature ( with void) but the more spezialized will be used (the second).
But why does it not work with int ? The second one with void would still be the prefered one would't it ?

Would the =int not match SFINAE ?

thanks!

Comment: [How does `void_t` work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work)

Comment: thanks this link helped

Comment: It is also answered in the [video itself](https://youtu.be/a0FliKwcwXE?t=1922).

Answer (score 4):

`void` is needed so that the result of that `void_t<decltype(...)>` expression will match the default argument for the primary template.

Think about the cases in which the classes are and are not assignable:

**Are assignable:**

```
void_t<decltype(std::declval<_Tp&>() = std::declval<_Up&>())>
//reduces to
void_t<type given from assignment>
//reduces to
void
```

**Are not assignable:**

```
void_t<decltype(std::declval<_Tp&>() = std::declval<_Up&>())>
//substitution failure, remove from candidate set
```

Now in the assignable case, the partial specialization will only be selected if the template arguments match, i.e. they need to be of the form:

```
__is_assignable_helper_af2<_Tp, _Up, void>
```

We want client code to just pass two arguments rather than explicitly specifying the `void` argument for the SFINAE to take place, so we specify it in the default arguments:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up, typename = void>
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We could just as easily choose a type other than `void` for this, but using it makes it explicit that we don't care about the type, we are just using it to leverage SFINAE. For example, we could define `int_t` and have `int` as the default argument instead. So long as they match, we use the partial specialization when we want to.