# Looking for "is_comparable" typetrait

Tags: c++11, type-traits

I'm looking for an "`is_comparable<>`" typetrait but can't find any.

It's very easy to build one that checks if an `operator==` for a class was implemented, but this excludes global defined operators.

Is it impossible to implement a generic `is_comparable<>` typetrait?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I take it you mean a trait that, for two types `L` and `R` and
objects `lhs` and `rhs` of those types respectively, will yield `true` if 
the `lhs == rhs` will compile and `false` otherwise. You appreciate that
in theory `lhs == rhs` might compile even though `rhs == lhs`, or `lhs != rhs`,
does not.

In that case you might implement the trait like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class ...> using void_t = void;

template<typename L, typename R, class = void>
struct is_comparable : std::false_type {};

template<typename L, typename R>
using comparability = decltype(std::declval<L>() == std::declval<R>());

template<typename L, typename R>
struct is_comparable<L,R,void_t<comparability<L,R>>> : std::true_type{};
```

This applies a popular SFINAE pattern for defining traits that is explained
in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687389/1362568)

Some illustrations:

```
struct noncomparable{};

struct comparable_right
{
    bool operator==(comparable_right const & other) const {
        return true;
    }
};

struct any_comparable_right
{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator==(T && other) const {
        return false;
    }
};

bool operator==(noncomparable const & lhs, int i) {
    return true;
}

#include <string>

static_assert(is_comparable<comparable_right,comparable_right>::value,"");
static_assert(!is_comparable<noncomparable,noncomparable>::value,"");
static_assert(!is_comparable<noncomparable,any_comparable_right>::value,"");
static_assert(is_comparable<any_comparable_right,noncomparable>::value,"");
static_assert(is_comparable<noncomparable,int>::value,"");
static_assert(!is_comparable<int,noncomparable>::value,"");
static_assert(is_comparable<char *,std::string>::value,"");
static_assert(!is_comparable<char const *,char>::value,"");
static_assert(is_comparable<double,char>::value,"");
```

If you want the trait to require that equality is symmetric and that inequality
also exists and is symmetric you can see how to elaborate it yourself.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it doesn't work.  Even your static_assert fails when trying to compile this code with gcc. The Problem seems to be the "std::declval<L>() == std::declval<R>()" which doesn't get evaluated. Interestingly clang-3.8 throws an compile exception as I would expect.

Comment: @Gene Odd, it compiled for me with [gcc 5.2 live](https://goo.gl/0Le5lw) and [clang 3.6 live](https://goo.gl/uLkdnm).
Maybe you could post your failing compile?

Comment: Interesting... I used gcc 4.9.2 which also complains about the static_assert. My local example was also little more complicated. I added a pair definition at the end, which makes clang 3.6 live also fail unexpectly: https://goo.gl/OKsuIU

Comment: @Gene `Pair2` is a breaker, yes. sfinae is too late. If anyone
has succesfully implemented an [EqualityComparable concept]
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable)
they must have cracked this, but evidently I haven't.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more question: why is Pair2 a breaker? Is it because it's compare function is implemented as a non-member function?

Comment: @Gene Sort of, in the sense that we don't need to sfinae on a decltype to check at least for the *existence* of a member function, but if an
equality is symmetric it must have a global definition, and then there's
builtin in types, so probing `x == y` is really the only runner. The
problem is that `std::pair<X,Y>` by definition is bound to match
the "true" sfinae option - the operator is defined - but after that's 
committed, if X or Y don't deliver the definition of the operator,
the compiler barfs at once, and this is just one instance of a general
possibility with template types.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It works with GCC 4.9.3 at least. I have found only one issue here: any lambda will pass this check as comparable, but comparison of two lambdas does not make any sense.

Comment: This doesn't correctly check `std::map<int, std::any>` comparing to itself.