# Fallback to to_string() when operator<<() fails

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, tostring, template-meta-programming

I've seen types that have corresponding `to_string()` function, but haven't overloaded `operator<<()`. So, when inserting to stream, one has to `<< to_string(x)` which is verbose. I'm wondering whether it's possible to write a generic function that users `operator<<()` if supported and falls back to `<< to_string()` if not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SFINAE is overkill, use ADL.

The trick is to make sure that **an** `operator<<` is available, not necessarily the one supplied by the type definition:

```
namespace helper {
   template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& t)
   {
      return os << to_string(t);
   }
}
using helper::operator<<;
std::cout << myFoo;
```

This trick is commonly used in generic code which needs to choose between `std::swap<T>` and a specialized `Foo::swap(Foo::Bar&, Foo::Bar&)`.

Comment: I agree this is simpler for the case where you only want `operator<<` for type `T` defined in its `namespace` or else `to_string(T)` and nothing more, which, admittedly, is what the OP has asked for, so +1. If you need to dispatch further, this won't work. Also, the error messages generated by this solution might not be as helpful as they could be.

Comment: This is nice. But then I have to overload `operator<<()` for each type that only has overloaded `to_string()`. I want to avoid such tedious work.

Comment: @ling what?  Why do you think you have to do that?

Comment: What happens with `struct bob{ template<class T>friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, T&& t ); };`?  Is there not a risk of ambiguity?

Comment: @Lingxi: No, you don't have to do that for every type. That's why I made the `operator<<` a **template**. It will be instantiated for every type which you print.

Comment: @Yakk: Sounds like a fair concern, but I'm not sure what exactly you mean form just that snippet. Considering we're talking ADL, the exact namespaces matter. Also, are you trying to print `bob` objects or others?

Comment: There is an ambiguity issue. For example, the overload for `std::basic_string` have `std::basic_ostream` for the first operand. As a result, it won't be more specialized than the custom version.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98a1ec4b4d18c8d3) is a live example of what I mean.

Comment: @Lingxi: Good point. To be precise, that's because there's no `operator<<` for just `std::string`. The ambiguity is between two templates, and the idea of my solution is that a template candidate ranks worse than a non-template candidate. There's probably a hack around that, worsening overload candidates is a known technique.

Comment: I made a revision to your solution (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34946808/1348273)). I guess it solves my problem. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
template <typename T>
void print_out(T t) {
    print_out_impl(std::cout, t, 0);
}

template <typename OS, typename T>
void print_out_impl(OS& o, T t, 
                    typename std::decay<decltype(
                      std::declval<OS&>() << std::declval<T>()
                    )>::type*) {
    o << t;
}

template <typename OS, typename T>
void print_out_impl(OS& o, T t, ...) {
    o << t.to_string();
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/ZMUE8135)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct streamy
{
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const streamy& obj)
{
  return os << "streamy [" << static_cast<const void *>(&obj) << "]";
}

struct stringy
{
};

std::string
to_string(const stringy& obj)
{
  auto oss = std::ostringstream {};
  oss << "stringy [" << static_cast<const void *>(&obj) << "]";
  return oss.str();
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t
<
  std::is_same
  <
    std::string,
    decltype(to_string(std::declval<const T&>()))
  >::value,
  std::ostream
>&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
  return os << to_string(obj);
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << streamy {} << '\n';
  std::cout << stringy {} << '\n';
}
```

The generic `operator<<` will only be available if the expression `to_string(obj)` is well-typed for `obj` a `const T&` and has a result of type `std::string`. As you have already conjectured in your comment, this is indeed SFINAE at work. If the `decltype` expression is not well-formed, we will get a substitution failure and the overload will disappear.

However, this will likely get you into troubles with ambiguous overloads. At the very least, put your fallback `operator<<` into its own `namespace` and only drag it in locally via a `using` declaration when needed. I think you will be better off writing a named function that does the same thing.

```
namespace detail
{

  enum class out_methods { directly, to_string, member_str, not_at_all };

  template <out_methods> struct tag {};

  template <typename T>
  void
  out(std::ostream& os, const T& arg, const tag<out_methods::directly>)
  {
    os << arg;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void
  out(std::ostream& os, const T& arg, const tag<out_methods::to_string>)
  {
    os << to_string(arg);
  }

  template <typename T>
  void
  out(std::ostream& os, const T& arg, const tag<out_methods::member_str>)
  {
    os << arg.str();
  }

  template <typename T>
  void
  out(std::ostream&, const T&, const tag<out_methods::not_at_all>)
  {
    // This function will never be called but we provide it anyway such that
    // we get better error messages.
    throw std::logic_error {};
  }

  template <typename T, typename = void>
  struct can_directly : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T>
  struct can_directly
  <
    T,
    decltype((void) (std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<const T&>()))
  > : std::true_type {};

  template <typename T, typename = void>
  struct can_to_string : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T>
  struct can_to_string
  <
    T,
    decltype((void) (std::declval<std::ostream&>() << to_string(std::declval<const T&>())))
  > : std::true_type {};

  template <typename T, typename = void>
  struct can_member_str : std::false_type {};

  template <typename T>
  struct can_member_str
  <
    T,
    decltype((void) (std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<const T&>().str()))
  > : std::true_type {};

  template <typename T>
  constexpr out_methods
  decide_how() noexcept
  {
    if (can_directly<T>::value)
      return out_methods::directly;
    else if (can_to_string<T>::value)
      return out_methods::to_string;
    else if (can_member_str<T>::value)
      return out_methods::member_str;
    else
      return out_methods::not_at_all;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void
  out(std::ostream& os, const T& arg)
  {
    constexpr auto how = decide_how<T>();
    static_assert(how != out_methods::not_at_all, "cannot format type");
    out(os, arg, tag<how> {});
  }

}

template <typename... Ts>
void
out(std::ostream& os, const Ts&... args)
{
  const int dummy[] = {0, ((void) detail::out(os, args), 0)...};
  (void) dummy;
}
```

Then use it like so.

```
int
main()
{
  std::ostringstream nl {"\n"};  // has `str` member
  out(std::cout, streamy {}, nl, stringy {}, '\n');
}
```

The function `decide_how` gives you full flexibility in deciding how to output a given type, even if there are multiple options available. It is also easy to extend. For example, some types have a `str` member function instead of an ADL find-able `to_string` free function. (Actually, I already did that.)

The function `detail::out` uses [tag dispatching](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) to select the appropriate output method.

The `can_HOW` predicates are implemented using the [`void_t` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work) which I find very elegant.

The variadic `out` function uses the [“for each argument” trick](https://youtu.be/2l83JlqkzBk), which I find even more elegant.

Note that the code is C++14 and will require an up-to-date compiler.

Comment: Is this SFINAE? So when `to_string(x)` compiles, the `return os << to_string(obj);` overload exists and not otherwise? Could I use `std::enable_if` instead of `std::conditional`?

Comment: I think having the `<< to_string(x)` overload if `<< x` does not compile would be nice, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Yes, this is SFINAE. Please see the updated answer (especially in reply to your second comment). I thought about using `std::enable_if` but I couldn't find a straight-forward solution so I went with the admittedly somewhat confusing `std::conditional`.

Comment: Changed code to use `std::enable_if_t` and require the result is of type `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @MSalters (credits goes to him), this one solves my problem and should make a complete answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct foo_t {};

std::string to_string(foo_t) {
  return "foo_t";
}

template <class CharT, class Traits, class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<CharT, char>::value,
                        std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&>::type 
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, const T& x) {
  return os << to_string(x);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::string{"123"} << std::endl;
  std::cout << foo_t{} << std::endl;
}
```