# How to sum all the elements of a multi-dimensional std::vector?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, metaprogramming, stdvector

The idea is simple and straight-forward:
Keep breaking the `n` dimensional vector into `n-1` dimensional constituent vectors, until you have access to the primitive-datatype objects. Then add them all.

**The problem is, how to infer the return type?**

It can be done like this, but it already assumes the datatype of summing variable (return-type):

```
typedef int SumType;

template <class T>
T Sum (const T x)
{
    return x;
}

template <class T>
SumType Sum (const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    SumType sum = 0;
    for (const auto& x: v)
        sum += Sum(x);
    return sum;
}
```

---

But I don't want to do it like above. I feel like its against the spirit of meta-programming.

We must infer the return-type by keeping dissecting the vector into its constituent vectors until we reach the primitive-datatype objects, and then choose the return-type as the primitive-datatype.

Is it possible in C++ ? (I'm noob in meta-programming)

---

P.S.
`std::accumulate()` from `<numeric>` could have been helpful, but it by-passes the problem by inferring the return-type from its third argument `__init`.

Comment: SumType must be inferable at compile time, just like with Templates so the compiler knows which function prototypes to generate. You can look at `decltype` to define the return value of SumType from the base data. For a more flexible solution, look at wrapping the base data into a variant class like in scripting languages.

Comment: You probably want `SumType sum {}`. There's no apparent reason to assume numeric 0 can be converted to `SumType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without any template meta programming. You can let the compiler infer the type using `auto` and `decltype`:

```
template <class T>
T Sum(const T x) {
    return x;
}

template <class T>
auto Sum(const std::vector<T> &v) {
    decltype(Sum(v[0])) sum = 0;
    for (const auto &x : v)
        sum += Sum(x);
    return sum;
}
```

The return type of `Sum` is automatically deduced from `sum` and the type of `sum` is whatever `Sum(v[0])` returns. Eventually you will end up with the first version of `Sum` which returns `T` and the compiler knows that type.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff39d0b2e2aaf8ca)

Answer (score 2):

What we can do is use [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c)'s [`data_type` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616323/4342498) to get the the underlying type.  That is defined as

> ```
> template<class T> struct voider { typedef void type; };
>
> template<class T, class = void>
> struct data_type {
>     typedef T type;
> };
>
> template<class T>
> struct data_type<T, typename voider<typename T::value_type>::type>
>        : data_type<typename T::value_type> {};
> ```

Using that we can modify the primary `Sum` to

```
template <class T, class Ret = typename data_type<std::vector<T>>::type>
Ret Sum (const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    Ret sum = 0;
    for (const auto& x: v)
        sum += Sum(x);
    return sum;
}
```

So then you can use something like

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << Sum(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>{{{1},{2},{3}},{{4},{5},{6}}});
}
```

which outputs

```
21
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4fc7157deb684bb)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You've almost figured out the answer for yourself. Pay attention to this line:

```
sum += Sum(x);
```

The type of `sum`, which is what we’re after, must be something compatible for assignment with the result of our recursive call to `Sum`. One such type, given your requirements, is certainly the result type of the call.

We don't have to rely on just a fuzzy feeling though. Meta-programming is, after all, programming. You may not have realised it, but your problem is one of well-founded recursion which means that the principle of induction can guide us towards an answer.

- in the base case, we have a numerical, non-vector `element_type element;`, meaning our result type is… `element_type`. you've in fact already managed this step, it’s the first overload:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  T Sum(T element);
  ```
- in the recursive case we have:

  - `std::vector<element_type> vec;`
  - the induction hypothesis, i.e.:

    ```
    // given
    element_type element;
    // we know the following is well-formed and a numerical type
    using recursive_result_type = decltype( Sum(element) );
    ```

    Since the vector elements have type `element_type`, the induction hypothesis gives us that the result of calling `Sum` on them has all the properties we want. (The justification for our `+=` intuition is rooted here.) We have our anser: we use `recursive_result_type` as-is.

Now as it turns out that second overload cannot just be written e.g. like so:

```
// doesn't behave as expected
template<typename Element>
auto Sum(std::vector<Element> const& vec) -> decltype( Sum(vec.front()) );
```

The reason being that the current `Sum` overload being declared is *not* in scope in the return type (even though it is in the definition body). One way to work around that is to rely on class scope, which is more accommodating:

```
// defining a functor type with operator() overloads
// would work just as well
struct SumImpl {
    template<typename Element>
    static T apply(Element element)
    { return element; }

    template<typename Element>
    static auto apply(std::vector<Element> const& vec)
    -> decltype( apply(vec.front()) )
    {
        using result_type = decltype( apply(vec.front()) );
        result_type sum = 0;
        for(auto const& element: vec) {
            sum += apply(element);
         }
         return sum;
    }
};

template<typename Arg>
using sum_result_t = decltype( SumImpl::apply(std::declval<Arg const&>()) );

template<typename Arg>
sum_result_t<Arg> Sum(Arg const& arg)
{ return SumImpl::apply(arg); }
```

[<kbd>Coliru</kbd> demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/459fb5f9f6aaf89a)