# Compile time function evaluation, incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have the following template for checking if a type is `std::string` or not. It compiles fine on GCC, but fails on Clang. Which is the correct behavior? Is there a way to make it work on both?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> //Checks if T is string type, by testing for the existence of member type "traits_type"
class is_string
{
public:
    template<typename C> std::false_type test(...);
    template<typename C> std::true_type test(decltype(sizeof(typename C::traits_type)));

    enum {
    value = decltype(((is_string<T>*)nullptr) -> test<T>( sizeof(0) ))::value
    };
};

int main() {
cout<<is_string<string>::value<<endl;
}
```

Error on Clang:

```
trial.cpp:15:51: error: member access into incomplete type 'is_string<std::basic_string<char> >'
    value = decltype(((is_string<T>*)nullptr) -> test<T>( sizeof(0) ))::value
                                              ^
trial.cpp:20:7: note: in instantiation of template class 'is_string<std::basic_string<char> >' requested here
cout<<is_string<string>::value<<endl;
      ^
trial.cpp:8:7: note: definition of 'is_string<std::basic_string<char> >' is not complete until the closing '}'
class is_string
```

Comment: What a strange way to check if a type is an std::string...

Comment: I see that now. Still very new to metaprogramming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang is correct, because, as it says, the type is incomplete until it is finished being defined. I imagine that if you turn on `-pedantic` then you'll get errors in gcc also.

A simpler way to do what you want is to just use `std::is_same`:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_same<std::string, std::string>::value, "");
static_assert(not std::is_same<std::string, int>::value, "");
```

Comment: I do have other templates which do similar things, but is not as simple as using ``is_same ``. What should I be doing in such cases?

Comment: @user2308211: It depends on exactly what you are doing, but often you can (1) just use SFINAE to enable / disable code as appropriate and don't use a trait, or (2) look at the templates `std::enable_if`, also `void_t`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work

Comment: In case it's useful to someone, I finally went with
``template <typename T> ``

``using is_string = std::is_same<std::string,T>;``

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether `g++` is right or `clang` is right is already [answered by @ChrisBeck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35875531/434551).

You can simplify your implementation to:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_string
{
   static bool const value = std::is_same<std::string, T>::value;
};
```

Comment: I do need similar templates for other purposes. In general, check if a class has a particular member. How can I do that correctly?

Comment: @user2308211, it will be better to ask that in a different question.