# How to specialize a type based on whether a template parameter has an alias

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-specialization

I want to be able to specialize a type based on whether a container has a specified typedef for example

```
class SomethingElse {};
class Something {
    using Type = int;
};

static constexpr bool value = ChooseIfType<Something>::value;
```

Is there a way for `ChooseIfType` to return false when the type does not have the typedef `Type`?

I feel like there is an easy way to do this but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check for specific name within the class, but your question seems to be asking if you can tell if the type has any alias. Which is it?

Comment: @krzaq Clarified that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) (or a C++11 alternative):

```
template<typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct ChooseIfType : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct ChooseIfType<T, std::void_t<typename T::Type>> : std::true_type {};
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1RczxAYwcuPQBv7x)

The solution makes use of SFINAE. The default is never malformed and creates a trait with value false. The compiler tries to match all template specializations (only one in this case). If `T` has a member type `Type`, then `ChooseIfType<T, void_t<typename T::Type>>` is more specialized than `ChooseIfType<T, void_t<>>`. If it doesn't, then it's not a viable specialization and the default is selected, but Substitution Failure Is Not An Error.

as per cppreference, a C++11 `void_t` implementation could look like this:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

Comment: Could you explain how that is working?  What happens when the default substitution for void_t is malformed?

Comment: @Curious Is that to your liking?

Comment: But both `void_t<>` and `void_t<typename T::Type>` are the same right?  As per http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

Comment: @Curious both yield `void`, yes.  Maybe look at this answer for futher details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work

Comment: Thanks!  That makes it clear.  So its only because the void_t with the specialization is "more specialized"