# How to make compiler differentiate f(double...) and f(int, double...)

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, constructor-overloading

I am writing a small library for working with polynomials.

The main class is called `poly` and it contains 4 overloaded constructors.

An object of class `poly` is a representation of one polynomial.

Full code can be viewed here: https://github.com/IQ8QI/polynomial-lib

In `./test-poly/test-all.cpp` I am trying to create an object of class `poly`:

```cpp
poly::poly my_poly = poly::poly((double)6.0, -2.0, 4.0);
```

Constructors of class `poly` are:

```cpp
//Create polynomial using just numbers
poly(double values...);

//Create polynomial using vector<double>
poly(vector<double> values);

//Create polynomial with non-zero base
poly(int base, double values...);

//Create polynomial with non-zero base and vector
poly(int base, vector<double> values);
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving a compilation error:

```
./test-all.cpp:20:63: error: call of overloaded ‘poly(double, double, double)’ is ambiguous
   20 |         poly::poly my_poly = poly::poly((double)6.0, -2.0, 4.0);
      |                                                               ^
In file included from ./test-all.cpp:3:
././../polynomial-lib/polynomial.hpp:22:17: note: candidate: ‘poly::poly::poly(int, double, ...)’
   22 |                 poly(int base, double values...);
      |                 ^~~~
././../polynomial-lib/polynomial.hpp:16:17: note: candidate: ‘poly::poly::poly(double, ...)’
   16 |                 poly(double values...);
      |                 ^~~~
```

I understand that the compiler is unable to determine which constructor to use.

I want to stay with solution that there are 4 constructors poly().

To resolve the issue, I can change 2 of the constructors into builder functions, but I don't like it:

```cpp
//Create polynomial with non-zero base
poly special_poly(int base, double values...){
        poly temp_poly = poly(values...);
        temp_poly.set_base(base);
        return temp_poly;
}

//Create polynomial with non-zero base and vector
poly special_poly(int base, vector<double> values){
        poly temp_poly = poly(values);
        temp_poly.set_base(base);
        return temp_poly;
}
```

Can it be done without builder functions?

Comment: please include a [mcve].

Comment: dont use c varargs in c++. c++ has typesafe variadic templates, that avoid this and many other issues

Comment: Don't use `poly(double values...)` instead use variadic templates. [Is there a case where vararg functions should be preferred over variadic templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339209/is-there-a-case-where-vararg-functions-should-be-preferred-over-variadic-templat)

Comment: but why do you need a vararg constructor in the first place? You already have one that uses a vector. Simply remove `poly(int base, double values...);` and `poly(double values...);`

Comment: perhaps you actually want one single constructor `poly(std::initializer_list<double> values,int base = 0)`

Comment: [Named constructors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor) might be a better solution

Comment: Which ctor you want to be used for `poly((double)6.0, -2.0, 4.0)`?

Comment: minimal example to reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/4WGnv886P. I fully agree with above comments by I'm curious about what conversion rules makes it ambiguous as (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876671/21691539) the full vararg version should be a worst match in my understanding.

Comment: `poly::poly((double)6.0 ...` - that cast is pointless. `6.0` is already a `double`.

Comment: Even if you could overload varargs like this, it would be useless as there's no way to tell how many arguments any given call has.  Use a variadic template instead.

Comment: `poly(vector<double> values);` -- This incurs an unnecessary copy.  You should be passing the vector by const reference, not by value: `poly(const std::vector<double>& values);`.  You have the same issue with other member functions that take a `vector` as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need c varargs when you can use c++ variadic templates which are typesafe. However, you already have a constructor that takes a `std::vector`, so I see no need for more than a single constructor:

```
#include <vector>


struct poly{
    std::vector<double> coeffs;
    int base = 0;
    poly(std::vector<double> c,int b = 0) : coeffs(std::move(c)),base(b) {}
};

int main() {
    poly p1{{1.0,2.0,3.0}};
    poly p2{{1.0,2.0,3.0},0};
}
```

I stayed with `std::vector` passed by value because thats what you asked for. Though, if you never actually need to pass an already constructed vector, but just a list of `double`s to the constructor you can change the argument to be a `std::initializer_list<double>`. If you stay with `std::vector` consider to pass it as rvalue reference (see below comment by Jan Schultke).

Comment: You'd be better off passing the `std::vector` by rvalue reference and move-constructing `coeffs` in accordance with CppCoreGuidelines, or at least passing it by value.

Comment: @JanSchultke good point. My intention was to not change too much on OPs code, but then I changed it to the worse. I made it pass by value again and refered to your comment

Answer (score 2):

A C++17 compatible solution would look like this (demo https://onlinegdb.com/_ToNa_7J0):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// with a template you can specify multiple arguments (a pack).
// the enable_if_t checks that all the individual arguments are of type double (nice bonus : no implicit conversion from int/float to double)
template<typename... args_t>
auto f(args_t&&... args) -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<double,args_t> && ...),void>
{
    std::cout << "All doubles\n";
}

template<typename... args_t>
auto f(int arg, args_t&&... args) -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<double,args_t> && ...),void>
{
    std::cout << "First one is an int the rest is all doubles\n";
}

int main()
{
    f(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    f(1,2.0,3.0);
    // f(1,2.f,3.0); // This one should not compile, there is a float argument in there

    return 0;
}
```

And outputs :

```
All doubles
First one is an int the rest is all doubles
```

Comment: This is great solution, this is what I asked for. But after seeing the call:
```
    f(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    f(1,2.0,3.0);
```
I consider it easy to make mistake and I will use other solution of 463035818_is_not_an_ai
Doing this is a little less error prone:
```
    poly p1{{1.0,2.0,3.0}};
    poly p2{{1.0,2.0,3.0},0};
```

Comment: That's fine. I usually kind of avoid initializer lists.  `template<std::size_t> f(double (&values)[N])` and `template<std::size_t N> f(int value,double (&values[N])` syntax would give you the same calling semantics but then without initializer lists. But both would still allow for implicit conversion to doubles.