# Why does decltype(declval<T>().func()) work where decltype(&T::func) doesn't?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, sfinae, member-functions

I was trying to detect the presence of a member function `baz()` in a template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct ImplementsBaz : public std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct ImplementsBaz<T, decltype(&T::baz)> : public std::true_type { };
```

But it always produces false:

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar { void baz() {} };

std::cout << ImplementsBaz<Foo>::value << std::endl;  // 0
std::cout << ImplementsBaz<Bar>::value << std::endl;  // also 0
```

Using `declval` and *calling* the method does work, though:

```
template<typename T>
struct ImplementsBaz<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().baz())> : public std::true_type { };
```

Of course, now this can only detect a `baz` function with 0 arguments. **Why is the specialization correctly selected when using `declval<T>().baz()`, but not `decltype(&T::baz)`?**

Comment: Just a guess: What happens if you remove the default ``= void`` in the general template?

Comment: Then `ImplementsBaz<Foo>::value` is illegal: `too few template arguments`

Comment: Ah, yes, I did overlook that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `void_t` "detection idiom", then it *does* work as expected:

```
template <typename...> using void_t = void;

template <typename T>
struct ImplementsBaz<T, void_t<decltype(&T::baz)>> : std::true_type {};


struct Bar { void baz() {} };

static_assert(ImplementsBaz<Bar>::value); // passes
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/132iGv)

As to *why*, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work) explains in detail how the "`void_t` trick" works. To quote from the accepted answer:

> It's as if you had written `has_member<A, void>::value`. Now, the template parameter list is compared against any specializations of the template `has_member`. Only if no specialization matches, the definition of the primary template is used as a fall-back.

In the original case, `decltype(&T::baz)` is not `void`, so the specialization does not match the original template and so is not considered. We need to use `void_t` (or some other mechanism, such as a cast) to change the type to `void` so that the specialisation will be used.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why that would cause the partial specialization to not be used — do you know why / know of any resources that explain it?

Comment: Thanks, makes sense: _"It's as if you had written `has_member<A, void>::value`. Now, the template parameter list is compared against any specializations of the template has_member. Only if no specialization matches, the definition of the primary template is used as a fall-back."_

Comment: @jtbandes That is a great quote, I've incorporated it into the answer, hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
decltype(&T::baz, void())
```

Your example with `decltype(std::declval<T>().baz())` and

```
struct Bar { void baz() {} };
```

works because `baz()` return `void` so the `void` match the default `typename = void` in the not specialized `Implements_baz` struct.

But if you define `Bar` as follows

```
struct Bar { int baz() { return 0; } };
```

you obtain `false` from `Implement_baz` because `baz()` return `int` that doesn't match `void`.

Same problem with `decltype(&T::baz)`: doesn't match `void` because return the type of a method.

So the solution (well... a possible solution) is use `decltype(&T::baz, void())` because return `void` if `T::baz` exist (or fail, and return nothing, if `T::baz` doesn't exist).

Comment: This is probably the best, unless the user only wants to match functions T::baz with void return type.

Comment: @jwimberley - would be a different problem; in that case the OP solution is a good solution but remain the problem that works only if `baz()` receive no arguments (or if the developer know the types of the arguments).

Answer (score 1):

This is because `decltype(&T::baz)` is an error and the partial specialization is never instantiated.  There is no static member called `baz` in `T` (i.e. `Bar`).

The second one does the right thing, i.e. call the method on an instance and then use the return type of that.

---

If you want to detect the presence of the method regardless of what parameters you pass to it if there is only one overload.

```
template <typename Type, typename = std::enable_if_t<true>>
struct ImplementsBaz : public std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};
template <typename Type>
struct ImplementsBaz<Type, std::enable_if_t<
                         std::is_same<decltype(&T::baz), decltype(&T::baz)>
                             ::value>> 
    : public std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};
```

---

If you want to detect the presence of that method if it contains overloads, take a look at the [member detection idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector).  Basically it assumes that a method with that name exists and then if there is another method with that name then the traits class goes into error and selects the right `true_type` specialization or similar.  Take a look!

Comment: I think your first answer was actually right — it seems the return type does matter. `&Bar::baz` should be a valid expression, so is there any way to do this using `decltype(&T::baz)`?

Comment: The discrepency persists even if baz is made static.

Comment: @jwimberley in that case the expression evaluates to an address, which is still not of type `void`

Comment: @jtbandes not sure if there is any other way but it's straightforward to use `declval` to pretend calling the method on an instance.  That's what `declval` was meant for

Comment: @Curious How about making it argument-type agnostic? using `declval<T>().baz()` requires explicitly passing arguments to baz, but I was interested in detecting the presence of a baz method regardless of argument type(s).

Comment: Why can’t it be a pointer-to-member?  (Not that it has type `void`!)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use

```
template<typename T>
struct ImplementsBaz<T, typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::baz)(T)>::type > : public std::true_type { };
```

Or, if you prefer for readability,

```
template<typename T>
using BazResult = typename std::result_of<decltype(&T::baz)(T)>::type;

template<typename T>
struct ImplementsBaz<T, BazResult<T> > : public std::true_type { };
```

This will only work if it just your intention to match functions `T::baz` with a void return type, although the same is true of your alternate working solution. It also has the deficiency of only working if there are no parameters, so it is only different from your second solution in style, unfortunately.