# Is `void_t` necessary to check if a class has a method with a specific signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, c++17

When I first learned how to check a specific signature in a class, I was taught to use `std::void_t` and write some code like this:

```
template<typename T, typename =void>
class HAS:public false_type{};

template<typename T>
class HAS<T,void_t<decltype(declval<T>().print())>>:public true_type{};
```

And this snippet of code will check if a class has the method named "`print()`". It works well.

But when I tried to remove the `std::void_t`, it still worked.

The code looks like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
class HAS:public false_type{};

template<typename T>
class HAS<T,decltype(declval<T>().print())>:public true_type{};
```

So I am confused if "`std::void_t`" is necessary to check if a class has a method with a specific signature? Or that's only a coincidence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work) explains in detail how `void_t` (otherwise known as the detection idiom) works. The key point is that the specialisation will only be considered if the type of the second template parameter evaluates to `void`.

In this case, it just so happens that your `print()` method returns `void`, so `decltype(declval<T>().print())` is also void. But if your `print()` returned something else, say `bool`, then the specialisation would not match and would not be used.

Comment: Thanks, when I was waiting for the answers about this question, I changed the return type of print to int. And as you say, It failed to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a coincidence then!

Answer (score 4):

> "void_t" is necessary to check if a class has a method with a specific signature?

+1 for the Tristan Brinde answer; but my answer is: `std::void_t` helps but (in your case) isn't necessary.

You can use the comma trick

```
decltype(std::declval<T>().print(), void())
```

The following is a compiling (in C++11 too; `std::void_t` is available only from C++17) full example

```
struct foo
 { };

struct bar
 { int print () const { return 0; } };

template <typename T, typename = void>
class HAS
   : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
class HAS<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().print(), void())>
   : public std::true_type
 { };

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( HAS<foo>::value == false, "!" );
   static_assert( HAS<bar>::value == true,  "!!" );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I am confused if "`std::void_t`" is necessary

To me it is not entirely clear what you mean by that.  If you mean the expression SFINAE which is utilized by `void_t` then the answer is **yes**.  If you mean whether you need to explicitly mention `void_t`, then the answer is **no**.

For example in C++17 you can make use of the [`is_detected`](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf) method, which is also part of [`std::experimental`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).  For other approaches see the other answers.

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template < typename T >
using print_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().print());

template < typename T >
using has_print = std::experimental::is_detected< print_t, T >;

struct A {};

struct B { void print() {} };

int main()
{
  static_assert( has_print<A>::value == false );
  static_assert( has_print<B>::value == true  );
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xF4SW5x7B2Xd8JPB)</kbd>