# How does a compiler distinguish between two variations of "vector::insert"?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm implementing a simple `std::vector`. There are two `insert` functions:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
typename Vector<T, Allocator>::iterator
Vector<T, Allocator>::insert(const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value)
{
    checkIterator(pos);
    auto p = const_cast<iterator>(pos);
    if (count == 0) {
        return p;
    }
    for (size_type i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        p = insert(p, value);
    }
    return p;
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
template <typename InputIt>
typename Vector<T, Allocator>::iterator
Vector<T, Allocator>::insert(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    checkIterator(pos);
    auto p = const_cast<iterator>(pos);
    if (first == last) {
        return p;
    }
    for (auto iter = first; iter != last; ++iter) {
        p = insert(p, *iter);
        ++p;
    }
    return p - (last-first);
}
```

But when I want to use first `insert` function, the compiler invokes the second one:

```
Vector<int> vi = {1, 2, 3};
vi.insert(vi.begin(), 3, 4); // get compile error, using insert(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last).
```

Why compiler chooses the second function, and how to modify my code to make it right?

Comment: The specification of `std::vector` relies on "compiler magic" for this case: it says that the iterator version is not selected unless the deduced type would comply with `InputIterator` requirements.   I guess when Concepts goes live you could express that easily in your own code; I'm not sure exactly what you can do before then

Comment: @M.M Why does it use compiler magic instead of regular user metaprogramming + sfinae?

Comment: Change one of the arguments so that it is a different type ... for example, by appending a `U` to the literal for the `size_type`, or by explicitly adding a cast.

Comment: @NirFriedman I don't know the rationale

Comment: g++ 7.1 apparently implements the current specification of concepts, but I can't find any predefined concept for checking InputIterator

Comment: @M.M. Where does the standard specify that this must rely on compiler magic? Concepts are not required in order to determine if a type meets complies with `InputIterator` requirements.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the standard says "If [these functions] are called with a type InputIterator that does not qualify as an input iterator, then these functions shall not participate in overload resolution."

Comment: @M.M. Okay, but how does that imply that there is compiler magic involved, since that qualification can be checked with template metaprogramming, and the functions can be consequently disabled with SFINAE?

Comment: @M.M OP looks to have copied members out of `std::vector` from the standard or some similar reference, and not realised there are extra conditions that make `std::vector` nice to use. When I look at my platform's implementation of `std::vector`, I see a bunch of SFINAE around the InputIterator overload. Not very "compiler magic"

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, doing this fully correctly is a problem. However, you can do something that is reasonable (and will work in this case). Basically,  you need to conditionally enable the second overload dependent on whether the deduced type `InputIt` actually meets the requirements for input iterator. There's a whole list of input iterator requirements: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator. However, we'll just focus on one that will solve this situation and most common cases for us. Namely, we'll verify that the type `InputIt` actually has a correct `operator*`. We use the [void_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work) trick to build a trait for this:

```
template <class ... T> using void_t = void;

template <class T, class = void>
struct has_iterator_deref : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_iterator_deref<T, std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::reference,
                 decltype(*std::declval<T>())>::value>> : std::true_type {};
```

The long and short of it is, that this struct will ensure that an instance of `T` can be dereferenced with `*` and yields the same type as `iterator_traits<T>::reference`. Having done that, we now use this to sfinae the second overload:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
template <typename InputIt, class = enable_if_t<has_iterator_deref<T>::value>>
typename Vector<T, Allocator>::iterator
Vector<T, Allocator>::insert(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last)
...
```

If you are feeling frisky, you can in fact go through the entire list of Input Iterator requirements, and as far as I can see, build a trait that detects if each one is present, and then finally take the conjunction to do exactly correct detection to ensure that InputIt meets the Input Iterator concept. It's rather a pain though.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The first line in the question is: "I'm implementing a simple std::vector"

Comment: I just got a error says : "no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>", there's something wrong in `is_same<...>` I think.

Comment: This works! But when I use `iter = vi.insert(vi.cend(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end())`, the compiler invoke `insert(const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value)`, guess I have more works to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple way to do this is to rely on
`iterator_traits::iterator_category` from `<iterator>`

It could look something like this:

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename It>
using iterator_category_t = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;

template<typename T>
class container
{
public:
    template <typename InputIt, typename ItCat = iterator_category_t<InputIt>>
    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last);
    // the rest
```

This will SFINAE away things like `int`, since they don't fulfill any iterator category.

This has the added benefit that you can dispatch on `ItCat{}` inside the implementation, if you have different algorithms for different iterator
categorys.