# Why SFINAE works incorrect for me in this case and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I am trying to leave in `struct A` one function `foo` (prints 0) if its parameter have template method `isA<void>` and another (prints 1) if haven't. This code (reduced to minimal example below) compiles (tried with gcc 6.1.0 and clang-3.9.0 with explicit `--std=c++14` option) and runs.

But it prints 1, though, I am sure, that it shall print 0. I wonder where am I wrong, but real question is: how to make this work correct?

Please only C++14 solutions.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using std::enable_if;
using std::declval;
using std::true_type;
using std::false_type;
using std::cout;

template<int M>
struct ObjectX
{
  template<typename C>
  bool isA() { return false; }
};

struct XX : ObjectX<23456> {
  int af;
};

template <typename ObjType> using has_dep = decltype(declval<ObjType>().template isA<void>());

template <typename, typename = void>
struct has_isa : public false_type {};

template <typename ObjType>
struct has_isa<ObjType, has_dep<ObjType> > : public true_type {};

template<typename ObjType>
struct A
{
  template<typename T = void>
  typename enable_if<has_isa<ObjType>::value, T>::type
  foo() {
    cout << "called foo #0" << "\n";
  }

  template<typename T = void>
  typename enable_if<!has_isa<ObjType>::value, T>::type
  foo() {
    cout << "called foo #1" << "\n";
  }
};

int
main()
{
  A<XX> axx;
  // XX().template isA<void>(); -- to check, that we can call it and it exists
  axx.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `has_isa` will not automatically try to instantiate the specialization with `has_dep` instead of the one with `void` if you give no second template parameter.

Comment: @Albjenow this approach works if function member is not template. Try minor changes to code (remove template C and fix has_dep) and you will see that everything else correct. It shall try to do it because more restricted specialization always wins against less restricted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in this program.

---

First, `has_dep<XX>` is `bool`. When we try `has_dep<XX>`, adding the default template arguments means this is really `has_dep<XX, void>`. But the specialization is `has_dep<XX, bool>` - which doesn't match what we're actually looking up. `bool` does not match `void`. That's why `has_dep<XX>` is `false_type`. The solution to this is [`std::void_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687389/2069064), and I'd suggest reading through that Q/A to get an idea for why it works. In your specialization, you need to use `void_t<has_dep<ObjType>>` instead.

---

Second, this is not right:

```
template<typename T = void>
typename enable_if<has_isa<ObjType>::value, T>::type
```

SFINAE only happens in the immediate context of substitution, and class template parameters are not in the immediate context of function template substitution. The right pattern here is:

```
template <typename T = ObjType> // default to class template parameter
enable_if_t<has_isa<T>>         // use the function template parameter to SFINAE
foo() { ... }
```

---

Make those two fixes, and the program works as intended.

Comment: void_t is C++17, but I got the idea, thanks, I definitely can write my own wrapper, similar to it

Answer (score 2):

Your sfinae fails because `has_isa` chooses the wrong specialization.

The use of `has_isa<T>` must be either the default implementation or the specialized version.

As you defined, you have a default argument to void:

```
//   default argument ---------v
template <typename, typename = void>
struct has_isa : public false_type {};
```

Then in the expression `has_isa<T>`, the second parameter must be void. It's roughly the same as writing `has_isa<T, void>`.

The problem is this:

```
template <typename ObjType>
struct has_isa<ObjType, has_dep<ObjType>> : public true_type {};
//                      ^--- what's that type?
```

Even though template partial ordering would consider this "overload" more specialized, it won't be chosen. Look at the definition of `has_dep`:

```
struct XX {
  template<typename C> bool isA() { return false; }
};

template <typename ObjType>
using has_dep = decltype(declval<ObjType>().template isA<void>());
```

Hey, that type `has_dep<T>` is the return type of `t.isA<void>()` which is `bool`!

So the specialized version look like this:

```
template <typename ObjType>
struct has_isa<ObjType, has_dep<ObjType>> : public true_type {};
//                      ^--- really, this is bool in our case
```

So in order for this to work, you must call `has_isa<T, bool>`. As this is impractical, you should define your specialization as this:

```
template <typename ObjType>
struct has_isa<ObjType, void_t<has_dep<ObjType>>> : public true_type {};
```

Where `void_t` is defined as so:

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void; // beware for msvc
```

As such, `has_isa<T>` will always consider the specialization, because we send `void` as the second template parameter, and now our specialization always result with `void` as second parameter.

---

Also, as stated by Barry, your function is not correctly formed as sfinae only appears in immediate context. You should write it like this:

```
template<typename T = ObjType>
typename enable_if<has_isa<T>::value, void>::type
foo() { //                 ^--- sfinae happens with T
  cout << "called foo #0" << "\n";
}
```

If you don't wish to expose the template parameter, simply make the function private:

```
template<typename ObjType>
struct A {
public:
    void foo() {
        foo_impl();
    }

private:
    template<typename T = ObjType>
    typename enable_if<has_isa<T>::value, void>::type
    foo_impl() {
      cout << "called foo #0" << "\n";
    }

    template<typename T = ObjType>
    typename enable_if<!has_isa<T>::value, void>::type
    foo_impl() {
      cout << "called foo #1" << "\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you specialize the wrong class:

You should force `has_dep` to return `void`.

```
template <typename ObjType> using has_dep = decltype(static_cast<void>(declval<ObjType>().template isA<void>()));
```

So here

```
template <typename ObjType>
struct has_isa<ObjType, has_dep<ObjType> > : public true_type {};
// It is really <bjType, void> you specialize.
```