# Using specialization to test the existence of a value within a class

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Lets say I have the following class:

```
struct Color
{
   enum {
      blue,
      red,
      unknown
   };
};
```

I would like to test in compile time if the class Color has the unknown value.

I thought the following could work but it is currently returning an incorrect result.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename U = T>
struct test
{
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct test<T, decltype(T::unknown)>
{
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << test<Color>::value << std::endl; //prints 0
}
```

Could you provide some insight on how I can accomplish the check?
Or what is wrong with my example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `test<Color>`, we first instantiate the primary specialization of `test`, which includes filling in the default template parameters. So we get `test<Color, Color>`.

Next, we try to see if any of the specializations match. The one specialization is for `test<Color, Color::<unnamed>>`. This doesn't match, so we stick with the primary!

This type mismatch is why [`void_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687389/2069064) exists - so that our defaulted template parameter on the primary can match the specialization:

```
template <typename T, typename U = void>
//                              ~~~~~~~
struct test
{
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct test<T, void_t<decltype(T::unknown)>>
//             ~~~~~~~                    ~
{
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Also, prefer to just inherit from `false_type` and `true_type`, respectively.