# Template template class predicate not working in partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, enable-if

I have many `EnableIf` traits that basically check whether the input type satisfies an interface.  I was trying to create a generic `Resolve` trait that can be used to transform those into a boolean trait.

Something like this - https://wandbox.org/permlink/ydEMyErOoaOa60Jx

```
template <
  template <typename...> class Predicate,
  typename T,
  typename = std::void_t<>>
struct Resolve : std::false_type {};
template <template <typename...> class Predicate, typename T>
struct Resolve<Predicate, T, Predicate<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now if you have an `EnableIf` trait like so

```
template <typename T>
using EnableIfHasFoo = std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo())>;
```

You can create a boolean version of that very quickly

```
template <typename T>
struct HasFoo : Resolve<EnableIfHasFoo, T> {};
```

Or the analogous variable template.

But for some reason the partial specialization is not working as expected.  Resolve does not work as intended.  See the output here - https://wandbox.org/permlink/ydEMyErOoaOa60Jx.  The same thing implemented "manually" works - https://wandbox.org/permlink/fmcFT3kLSqyiBprm

I am resorting to manually defining the types myself.  Is there a detail with partial specializations and template template arguments that I am missing?

Comment: I cannot find the reason, but you need the partial specialization to be `Resolve<Predicate, T, std::void_t<Predicate<T>>`. Then at that point, you can also remove the `std::void_t` in the alias.

Comment: btw, your code look a lot like the [dectection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot But then what is the predicate?  Just decltype()?  Very nice!  Also, confusing why the above approach doesn't work.

Comment: It can be an alias template to simply `decltype`. I don't know why, but the `void_t` must be in the partial specialization. I think it has to do with how partial ordering work.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot find the exact reason why your example don't work. If you want to dig more into the details of `std::void_t`, here's an [interesting explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27688405/2104697)

Even if I cannot explain it in depth, I would like to add another reliable syntax that is used in the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

```
template<
    template <typename...> class Predicate,
    typename T,
    typename = void>
struct Resolve : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Predicate, typename T>
struct Resolve<Predicate, T, std::void_t<Predicate<T>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
using EnableIfHasFoo = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
```

[live on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xX9kGp)

Comment: Have an upvote for the minimal change. But I deleted mine because I'm still guessing at the reasons.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks. I haven't found the reason either. It might be because the rule doesn't make the specialization more specialized.

Comment: Might be. I'm examining partial ordering at the moment to see why.

Comment: @StoryTeller I added a link to another answer that explains void_t. However, even that answer don't seem to explain your case completely.

Comment: This is an interesting take on what I was trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: @Curious I was sure it was about `std::void_t` being an alias to void, and mixed that with template argument deduction for the template specialization, but every experimentation showed me the contrary. Sorry I couldn't find the exact reason, but it has to do with template partial ordering or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your approach will fail is that `Predicate<T>>` in the third template parameter is **not** a non-deduced context. This causes the deduction to directly fail (see [[temp.alias]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias#2)), instead of using the deduced template arguments from elsewhere as in a non-deduced context.

You can wrap your `Predicate<T>>` to a non-deduced context to make it work:

```
template<class T>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <template <typename...> class Predicate, typename T>
struct Resolve<Predicate, T, typename identity<Predicate<T>>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oNT3nHIYVWeRJCgn)

Because inside a non-deduced context, the deduction won't happen for `Predicate<T>` part, instead, it will *use* the `Predicate` and `T` obtained from elsewhere.

As for why the usual detection-idiom (see [Guillaume Racicot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513816/8605791)) will work, it is because `std::void_t` as a template alias, will be replaced by `void` in deduction phase (see [[temp.alias]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.alias#2)), thus no deduction will happen.

Here are some examples to illustrate it more clearly:

```
template<class T>
using always_int = int;

template<template<class> class TT>
struct deductor {};

template<template<class> class TT, class T>
void foo(T, deductor<TT>) {}

template<template<class> class TT, class T>
void bar(T, deductor<TT>, TT<T>) {}

template<class T>
void baz(T, always_int<T>) {}

int main() {
    // ok, both T and TT are deduced
    foo(0, deductor<always_int>{});

    // ERROR, TT<T> is NOT a non-deduced context, deduction failure
    bar(0, deductor<always_int>{}, 0);

    // ok, T is deduced, always_int<T> is replaced by int so no deduction
    baz(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: So... why does it usually work with `void_t`? It's an alias template too.

Comment: @StoryTeller Because the deduction starts from `std::void_t<Predicate<T>>>`, `std::void_t` is already known.

Comment: Sorry, by usually I meant `std:void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo)>`

Comment: @StoryTeller `decltype(std::declval<T>().foo)` is a non-deduced context, compiler won't deduce from it.

Comment: Yeah, it is (should really print that bullet list). But shouldn't the equivalence of alias template specializations make this moot? I.e., it should be as though the OP wrote directly `std::void_t<declval<...>(...).foo>`, no? Sorry for flood of questions, I  was just staring at these passages for too long.

Comment: Oh. no wait. I see now. Great answer! That void_t we hide is failing immediately because the specialization *needs* to be replaced by its equivalent type!