# Generalizing is_detected with variadic function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am trying to modify the `is_detected` idiom to allow passing variadic arguments to it. I need this since some of my detected member functions will have user provided arguments.

So far, this is what I got working. You give the extra args to `is_detected_args_v`, and in theory, the template specialization would kick in and compile correctly. Thus giving `std::true_type`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

// slightly modified (and simplified) is_detected
template <template <class, class...> class Op, class T, class = void, class...>
struct is_detected_args : std::false_type {};
template <template <class, class...> class Op, class T, class... Args>
struct is_detected_args<Op, T, std::void_t<Op<T, Args...>>, Args...>
        : std::true_type {};

template <template <class, class...> class Op, class T, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_detected_args_v
        = is_detected_args<Op, T, Args...>::value;

// has_func, checks the function starts with int, and then Args&...
template <class T, class... Args>
using has_func = decltype(std::declval<T>().func(
        std::declval<int>(), std::declval<Args&>()...));


// has the func
struct obj {
    void func(int, double&, double&) {
        printf("potato\n");
    }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    obj o;

    if constexpr(is_detected_args_v<has_func, obj, double, double>) {
        double d = 0;
        double d2 = 42;
        o.func(42, d, d2);
    }
}
```

You can run the example here (tested on all 3 compilers) : https://wandbox.org/permlink/ttCmWSVl1XVZjty7

The problem is, the specialization is never chosen and the conditional is always false. My question is two-folds.

1. Is this even possible?
2. Why doesn't `is_detected` get specialized?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is misunderstanding what `void_t` does. As a refresher, see [how does `void_t` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687389/2069064). The key idea is that the primary template has a `void` parameter and the specialization has some complex thing that you want to check wrapped in `void_t` so that it *matches* the primary template's parameter. That isn't happening in your example.

We can fix it in two easy steps. First, you have this type `T` along with `Args...` There isn't actually any reason to split this up, and it's easier to look at if we don't have extraneous parameters. So here's your attempt just reduced (I also gave a name to the parameter which is supposed to be `void`):

```
template <template <class...> class Op, class AlwaysVoid, class...>
struct is_detected_args : std::false_type {};
template <template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct is_detected_args<Op, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Args...>
        : std::true_type {};

template <template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_detected_args_v = is_detected_args<Op, Args...>::value;
```

Now it should be easier to see what's missing: the `void` parameter! You're not passing in a `void` and you need to. That's an easy fix though:

```
template <template <class...> class Op, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_detected_args_v = is_detected_args<Op, void, Args...>::value;
//                                                              ~~~~~
```

And now it works as expected.

---

Cppreference also provides a complete implementation of [`is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) if you want to look at that too.

Comment: awesome! thanks you for the detailed explanation :)