# How to get a forwarding function to call a base template function that is declared after the forwarding function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a case where I need to have a forwarding function defined before a template base function is defined/declared.  However, if I call the forwarding function (`fwd`) that in turn calls the base function `test`, it says that the base template function is not visible (see the code below).  However, if `test` is called directly, everything works.

So my question is this, is it possible to have the forwarding function make a call to a base template function that is defined later in the compilation unit (before it is used but after the forwarding function)?  If not, do I have any options to work around this?  I would like to avoid a forward declaration before `fwd` as that would make use of the library I am developing harder.  I think if I could force `fwd` to be inline it would solve the problem but I have no way of doing that unless a macro is used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar<T>::value, int> = 0>
void test(const T& t)
{
  std::cout << "Scalar"  << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void fwd(T&& t)
{
  test(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template<typename T>
void test(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& t)
{
  std::cout << "vector vector of T" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  test(1);  //OK, prints Scalar
  fwd(1);   //OK, prints Scalar

  test(std::vector<std::vector<int>>()); //OK, prints vector vector of T

  // Causes compile error: Call to function 'test' that is neither visible in the template definition
  // nor found by argument dependent lookup
  fwd(std::vector<std::vector<int>>());

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `test` in `fwd` is a dependent name. It will be resolved into [two steps](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Lookup_rules):

> 1. Non-ADL lookup examines function declarations ... that are visible from *the template definition context*.
> 2. ADL examines function declarations ... that are visible from either *the template definition context* or *the template instantiation context*.

Given that the relative order of `test` and `fwd` should not be changed, one possible solution is to use a fake tag `struct` in the namespace to activate ADL:

```
namespace my_namespace
{
    struct Tag {};

    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_scalar<T>::value, int> = 0>
    void test(const T& t, Tag = Tag{}) {
        std::cout << "Scalar" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T> 
    void fwd(T&& t) {
        test(std::forward<T>(t), Tag{});
    }

    template<typename T>
    void test(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& t, Tag = Tag{}) {
        std::cout << "vector vector of T" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    my_namespace::test(std::vector<std::vector<int>>()); // OK
    my_namespace::fwd(std::vector<std::vector<int>>());  // OK, too
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wWoz89)

---

Depending on what `test` overloads you have, another solution might be to wrap these functions into `struct`s and use template specialization instead of function overloading:

```
template<class T>
struct Test {
    static void op(const T& t) {
        std::cout << "Scalar" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void fwd(T&& t) {
    Test<std::decay_t<T>>::op(std::forward<T>(t));
}

template<class T>
struct Test<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> {
    static void op(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& t) {
        std::cout << "vector vector of T" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    fwd(1);
    fwd(std::vector<std::vector<int>>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cRJCmU)

Comment: For the first solution, are you relying on this rule from the dependent name link to activate ADL?

"To make ADL examine a user-defined namespace, either std::vector should be  replaced by a user-defined class or its element type should be a user-defined 
class"

Comment: The first solution works better for me as its handy to have a template function that handles all of the scalars.  Once i use structs I start getting into ambiguity issues when combining those with the enable_if calls.

Comment: @dr_pepper "...or a dummy function argument can be added". I rely on the fact that the namespace that contains `Tag` will be examined. If you have another argument that is contained in that namespace (and in your example you don't), there is no need for `Tag`. With structs you can also use [`void_t` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work).