# How can I check if these structs has the specific type called "Foo"?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

```
#include <iostream>
```

/**** I am confused to apply sfinae method here ******/

```
template <typename T>
struct hasTypeFoo {

//..    
static constexpr bool value = true;

};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
struct A {

    using Foo = int;

};

struct B {


};
int main()
{

    constexpr bool b1 = hasTypeFoo<A>::value;
    constexpr bool b2 = hasTypeFoo<B>::value;

    std::cout << b1 << b2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t):

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct hasTypeFoo : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct hasTypeFoo<T, std::void_t<typename T::Foo>> : std::true_type { };
```

A very good explanation of how `std::void_t` works, can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work). It is used here to silently reject the specialization if `typename T::Foo` is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). e.g.

```
// primary template
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct hasTypeFoo {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

// partial specialization for types containing type Foo    
template <typename T>
struct hasTypeFoo<T, std::void_t<typename T::Foo>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Oow3pWWBNCzJsxbi)