# C++ partial template specialization issue

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization

Given a matrix class

```
using index_t = int;
template<index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct mat {
    // matrix implementation
};
```

I would like to have a generic way of obtaining the elementCount for a given type `T` that will work for both matrices and scalars. For example, I imagine being able to do this:

```
dimensionality<mat<1,2,double>>(); // returns 2
dimensionality<mat<2,2,float>>(); // returns 4
dimensionality<double>(); // returns 1
```

or perhaps something like this:

```
attributes<mat<1,2,double>>::dimensionality; // returns 2
attributes<mat<2,2,float>>::dimensionality; // returns 4
attributes<double>::dimensionality; // returns 1
```

#### My attempt:

I tried doing the following (thinking that I am partially specializing the `struct attributes`):

```
template<typename T>
struct attributes {};

template<typename S, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<S>::value>>
struct attributes<S> {                                        // <---  compiler error on this line
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = 1;
};

template<index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct attributes<mat<M, N, S>> {
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = M * N;
};
```

but I get a compiler error on the indicated line. Can you help me (either by suggesting a better approach, or to understand what I'm doing wrong)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the specialization cannot have more template parameters than the primary template, but your code puts `typename = std::enable_if_t` for the arithmetic case.

Secondly, in order to make this `std::enable_if_t` to work, it would need to result in something that makes the specialization more specialized than the primary template, not only valid. For that, you could use the [`void_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687389/3953764) trick:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct attributes {};

template <typename S>
struct attributes<S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<S>::value>> {
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = 1;
};
```

This also entails that the specialization for matrices should include this `void` parameter as well:

```
template <index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct attributes<mat<M, N, S>, void> {
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = M * N;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/843a91792fad6d2e)

---

Your trait could, however, be shortened to:

```
template <typename T>
struct attributes {
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "T must be arithmetic or mat");
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = 1;
};

template <index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct attributes<mat<M, N, S>> {
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = M * N;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ecd0c15af87062a)

That is, just consider arithmetic types in the primary template, when no specialization matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another template parameter with default type `void`, then specify the `std::enable_if` as the corresponding template argument in the partial specialization for arithmetic types. (And adjust the partial specialization for `mat` too.)

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct attributes {};

template<typename S>
struct attributes<S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<S>::value>> { 
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = 1;
};

template<index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct attributes<mat<M, N, S>, void> {
    static constexpr index_t dimensionality = M * N;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3uARFMJYMkjX5Ywy)

Answer (score 1):

#### Wrapping a trait-based static constant: std::integral_constant

You may want to make use of [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) from [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) to implement your trait,

> [...] `std::integral_constant` **wraps a static constant of specified type**. It is the base class for the C++ type traits.

as well as supply a helper variable template `dimensionality_v` for ease of use:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Default dimensionality 0.
template <class T, typename = void>
struct dimensionality : std::integral_constant<index_t, 0> {};

template <typename S>
struct dimensionality<S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<S>>>
    : std::integral_constant<index_t, 1> {};

template <index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct dimensionality<mat<M, N, S>> : std::integral_constant<index_t, M * N> {};

template <class T>
inline constexpr index_t dimensionality_v = dimensionality<T>::value;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fc85126bce998a3).

Alternatively, if you don't want to allow a default dimensionality for types that are neither fulfilling `std::is_arithmetic_v` nor equals `mat`:

```
template <class T, typename = void>
struct dimensionality {};

template <typename S>
struct dimensionality<S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<S>>>
    : std::integral_constant<index_t, 1> {};

template <index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct dimensionality<mat<M, N, S>> : std::integral_constant<index_t, M * N> {};

template <class T>
inline constexpr index_t dimensionality_v = dimensionality<T>::value;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d761c6fb7c7cd6a0).