# Extract signature from callable type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, std-function

I have a value which is of type `std::variant<char, int, double>`. In fact, I have several values stored in a `std::vector<value>`.

I want to be able to pass these values to several `callback` functions, if their signature matches the types of values. Here is my implementation:

```cpp
using value = std::variant<char, int, double>;
using values = std::vector<value>;

template<typename... Args>
using callable = std::function<void (Args...)>;

struct callback
{
    template<typename... Args>
    callback(callable<Args...> fn)
    {
        constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Args);
        fn_ = adapt(std::move(fn), std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }
    
    void operator()(const values& vv) const { fn_(vv); }
    
private:
    std::function<void (const values&)> fn_;

    template<typename... Args, std::size_t... Is>
    auto adapt(callable<Args...> fn, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return [fn_ = std::move(fn)](const values& vv) {
            /* if signature matches */ fn_(std::get<Args>(vv[Is])...);
        };
    }
};

using callbacks = std::vector<callback>;
```

Now I can do this and it works mostly well:

```cpp
void fn(char c, int i) { std::cout << "fn:" << c << i << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    values vv = { 'x', 42 };
    
    callback cb1{ std::function<void (char, int)>(fn) };
    callback cb2{ std::function<void (char, int)>([](char c, int i) { std::cout << "lambda:" << c << i << '\n'; }) };

    callbacks cbs = { cb1, cb2 };
    for(auto const& cb : cbs) cb(vv);

    return 0;
}
```

You can see working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58f207fa94cee57b).

I've reviewed several similar questions about (im)possibility of implicitly converting function pointers, lambdas, functors, etc. to `std::function`.

So my question is, what "glue" do I need into order to be able to do this:

```cpp
callback cb3 { fn };
callback cb4 { [](char c, int i) { } };
// same for other callable types
```

I thought of some sort of `function_traits` implementation to extract signature from a callable type and pass it to `std::function`. But looking at the code of [std::is_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) makes me think this will require a lot of boilerplate code.

I'd like to ask here if anyone can think of a more concise solution. Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to accomplish this using <s>sweat, blood and tears</s> partial specialization, SFINAE and [void_t trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work#27688405). I am now able to do this:

```
callback cb1 { fn };
callback cb2 { lambda };
callback cb3 { [](char c, int i) { std::cout << "lambda2:" << c << i << '\n'; } };

int x = 69;
callback cb4 { [x](char c, int i) { std::cout << "lambda3[x]:" << x << c << i << '\n'; } };
callback cb5 { ftor(x) };
```

Here is the [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fab266b57e65ae4). In this implementation `callback` can accept function pointers, lambdas (including capturing, but not generic) and functors.

Comment: it is unclear how this should work for functional objects, since they can have several different overloads for the `operator`

Comment: @d_kog consider this to be outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for your described use cases, what you want can be achieved by adding additional `callback` constructor templates.

```
template<typename... Args>
callback(void (*fn)(Args...)) : callback(callable<Args...>(fn)) {}
```

This constructor will match an argument that can decay to a function pointer, e.g. this constructor call now works

```
callback cb3{ fn }; // ok
```

Note that this new constructor simply delegates to your original constructor by explicitly casting the function pointer to a `callback<Args...>`.

---

Similarly, you can write a template that will match an argument that is a lambda.

```
template<typename Lambda>
callback(Lambda fn) : callback(+fn) {}
```

and now this constructor call works.

```
callback cb4{ [](char c, int i) { std::cout << "lambda:" << c << i << '\n'; } }; // ok
```

Note here that the delegation is to the constructor taking a function pointer. This is achieved by simply explicitly decaying the lambda to a function pointer with the unary `+` operator. Of course, that constructor will further delegate to your original constructor with the actual implementation.

---

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E3az8Y).

Comment: why the `+` in the lamba ctor?

Comment: @InnocentBystander As mentioned, `+` will cause a lambda to decay to a function pointer, which allows you to delegate to the constructor taking a function pointer. There are other ways of decaying the lambda as well, but `+` is a fairly idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: ah sorry missed the last paragraph. :) What would you recommend for the rest of the callable types? I.e. class member function, functor and `std::bind()` (not sure if I've missed anything else).

Comment: @InnocentBystander It depends on each one. You might need to do the cast explicitly at the call site for some cases, e.g. if the lambda that you pass captures anything.

Comment: cigien, if it's not too much to ask, would you mind adding overloads for capturing lambda and bind expressions? I can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: @InnocentBystander No, that's not what I meant actually. There may not be constructor overloads that will handle capturing lambdas at all, and so you'll have to be explicit at the call site, like you did for `cb1`, and `cb2`.

Comment: cigien, How does `std::function` do it then? Some sort of compiler assisted trick?

Comment: @InnocentBystander Actually, I don't think `std::function` does anything that can't be implemented in user code. There are certainly limits on what `std::function` will deduce if the template arguments are not specified.

Comment: "How does std::function do it": std::function only supports deduction from function pointers and non-generic function objects (i.e. has unique operator()). The constructor is constrained to take only things invocable like the signature, but that presupposes the signature except in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

As d_kog commented, the question itself is rarely the right one in C++. A callable need not have a unique signature. Therefore, you should re-frame the problem. Instead of trying to determine the signature to check for call-ability, check for call-ability directly.

Your callback has to do three fundamental things with a vector of values:

1. "Lift" the size to compile-time, e.g. turn the vector into a tuple or a pack.
2. visit the values, to get the value inside the variants.
3. apply the function to them, if possible.

Steps 2 and 3 are straightforward. The "find-the-signature" is being used to find the arity so that an index sequence and `vv[Is]...` gives you a pack (assuming vv's size() is checked first). Then you use `get<Args>` essentially to implement `visit`, but that is unnecessary.

But there are other options for step 1. For example, if you only support up to a certain number of arguments, this is effective:

```
template<typename F>
void call_helper(const values& vv, F&& f)
{
    switch (vv.size()) {
    case 0: std::forward<F>(f)(); break;
    case 1: std::forward<F>(f)(vv[0]); break;
    case 2: std::forward<F>(f)(vv[0], vv[1]); break;
    case 3: std::forward<F>(f)(vv[0], vv[1], vv[2]); break;
    default: throw std::out_of_range{"too many arguments to callback"};
    }
}
```

Then `adapt` becomes:

```
return [fn_ = std::move(fn)](const values& vv) {
    // lift from the vector to function arguments
    call_helper(vv, [&](const auto&... args) {
        // visit the arguments
        std::visit([&](const auto&... args_unwrapped) {
            // check invocability with the arguments
            if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(fn_), decltype(args_unwrapped)...>)
                // invoke
                std::invoke(fn_, args_unwrapped...);
            else
                throw std::runtime_error{"invalid argument types to callback"};
        }, args...);
    });
};
```

Then, you can support all manner of C++ callables:

```
callback cb1{ fn }; // function pointer
callback cb2{ [](char c, int i) { std::cout << "lambda:" << c << i << '\n'; } };
callback cb3{ [](auto c, auto i) { std::cout << "generic lambda:" << c << i << '\n'; }};
int j = 1000;
callback cb4{ [j](char c, int i) { std::cout << "capturing lambda[" << j << "]:" << c << i << '\n'; }};
callback cb5{ [](int c, int i) { std::cout << "implicit conversion allowed:" << c << i << '\n'; }};
callback cb6{ [] { /* "invalid argument types to callback" */ }};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fbn7eh)

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I was able to accomplish this (see the UPDATE in my answer) but plus1 for implementation accepting more types than mine. :)