# Decomposing C++17 function-like object in generic fashion?

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17 suppose I have a function-like object passed as a parameter to some template:

```
 template<typename F>
 void g(F f) {
    auto x = f(/*...*/);
 }
```

There are lots of different types F could be, such as a function pointer, a std::function, a lambda expression, and in fact any class type that implements `operator()`.

Is there any way to get the function-like objects arity and type of its parameters and the type of its return type?

I mean, ultimately F could be a class that overloads `operator()` with multiple different member functions, each with different arities, parameter types and return types - so there isn't a fully-general answer (unless there is some way to iterate that overload set, which I don't think there is).

But for the typical case where a function call expression involving f results in a single overload, is there a solution?

(also if there is any progress in C++20, worth mentioning too)

Comment: "*the typical case where a function call expression involving f results in a single overload*" Considering that a "single overload" could be a template function, I'm not sure how "typical" this case would be.

Comment: I meant an `operator()` overload that's a template. Like what you get with generic lambdas and the like.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Right, so if F has a member template `operator()` then that would instantiate to different things based on what arguments it is passed, so for the purposes of this question such a case is also out-of-scope (like multiple overloads).

Comment: My point is that it is a "typical case", so even if you can find an answer, it won't be a *useful* one.

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498688/extract-signature-from-callable-type/

Comment: And IMO @NicolBolas is 100% correct. Outside of very limited situations, this is both the wrong question to ask and the answer will be too limited to have utility.

Comment: @NicolBolas: @JeffGarrett: The motivating use case is calling the function-like object dynamically at run-time (think like Qt signals/slots, or exposing them to a scripting language like python, lua, javascript, etc).  You can't instantiate a template at runtime, so an answer that covers a member template `operator()` is not possible. An answer that only covers cases with a specific signature (like an ordinary non-template function, std::function instantiation, non-generic lamdbda expression) is not only useful, it is in fact, exhaustively so.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: You have failed to explain why calling a function requires knowing its interface like this. What are you trying to do by introspecting the functor? Isn't what matters is that it's callable given a set of parameters, *not* exactly how that happens? That is, if it is a template or overloaded member function, you can still call it so long as it takes the parameters you expect. So why do you need to introspect the callable like this?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Take a look at a C++ binding system for your favorite scripting language and how it works when exporting a function.  (say `boost::python` for a specific example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: @NicolBolas: Also, side note - the answer to your question is actually the same as the answer to why we can't have virtual member function templates. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++17's adds [deduction guides for `std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides), which we can use to do the deduce the function signature of non-overloaded function-like objects:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
constexpr auto do_something_with_the_signature(std::function<R(Args...)>) {
    // Assuming that you only care about the return type.
    // Otherwise, you may want some kind of wrapper to extract the signature to
    // avoid runtime cost
}

...

using some_type_computation =
    decltype(do_something_with_the_signature(std::function(f)));
```

If you only wanted the return type, you could just use:

```
using result_type = typename decltype(std::function(f))::result_type;
```

---

If you want to avoid `std::function` altogether because of the compile-time costs, you can implement your own version of the deduction guides for your own type (possibly as general as a `function_traits` type trait). A sketch of how you might implement the deduction guides yourself can be seen in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66038056/1896169