# C++ - Specify template value type

Tags: c++, templates

I have the function

```
// Helper to determine whether there's a const_iterator for T.
template <typename T>
struct hasConstIt {
private:
    template<typename C> static char test(typename C::const_iterator*);
    template<typename C> static int test(...);
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

// Check if a container contains an element.
template <typename Container, typename = std::enable_if_t<hasConstIt<Container>::value> >
bool contains(const Container & container, typename Container::value_type const & element) {
    return std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), element) != container.end();
}
```

How can I specify that the container value type must be a specific type? Say I want the container to contain `int`, then valid containers could be `vector<int>`, `deque<int>` etc.

Comment: What about `hasConstIt<Container>::value && std::is_same<typename Container::value_type, int>::value`? By the way, `hasConstIt` can be implemented much simpler using `std::void_t` trick.

Comment: @Evg This works, I forgot the `typename` in `std::is_same`... Can you tell me what the `std::void_t` trick is?

Comment: Prefer `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0` over `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>`. So you might have overloads, and cannot be hijacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::is_same` to check if a type is exaclty the same as a specified one. If you want to check both of your conditions at once, you can simply use logical operators in the `std::enable_if` conditon:

```
template <typename Container, typename = std::enable_if_t<
    (std::is_same<typename Container::value_type, int>::value &&
    hasConstIt<Container>::value)
    > >
bool contains(const Container & container, typename Container::value_type const & element) {
    return std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), element) != container.end();
}
```

Contrary to the other answer, this is SINAE friendly. But if you only want to make sure it does not compile if the user makes a mistake I'd go with the other solution because it will give you way better error messages.

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps3f6j).

If you can use C++20 you can use `requires` to constrain your template types. This is both SFINAE-friendly and gives you a nice error message.

```
template<typename Container>
requires (
    requires {
     typename Container::const_iterator; 
     typename Container::value_type; 
    } 
    && std::same_as<typename Container::value_type, int>
)
bool contains (const Container & container, typename Container::value_type const & element) {
    return true;
}
```

Or, if you need to constrain multiple functions you can define a concept

```
template<typename Container>
concept good_container = 
  requires(Container c) {        
   typename Container::const_iterator; 
   typename Container::value_type;                 
  } 
  && std::same_as<typename Container::value_type, int>;

template<good_container Container>
bool contains (const Container & container, typename Container::value_type const & element) {
    return true;
}
```

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/68r96E).

Comment: In the C++20 version, why not to use concepts (`std::same_as`) for the value type, too?

Comment: @Evg thanks fir the hint. I've updated my answer. I still feel somewhat unfamiliar with C++20 conceps :/

Answer (score 3):

You can get it done by using the `std::is_same_v` ans `static_assert`.

```cpp
template <typename Container>
bool contains(const Container& container, typename Container::value_type const& element) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Container::value_type, int>, "The container 'value_type' must be 'int'!");

    // You don't have to explicitly check if there is a 'const_iterator' because the STL containers specify 'cbegin()' and 'cend()'
    // which returns the 'Container::const_iterator'. So checking if these functions are there will be enough (for STL containers).
    return std::find(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), element) != container.cend();
}
```

Now if the `Container::value_type` is not `int`, it'll throw a compiler error stating that `The container 'value_type' must be 'int'!`

Bonus: Your `hasConstIt` can be written in a more *better* way (more readable and the IDE wont complain that the functions are undefined),

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct hasConstIt {
private:
    template<typename C> static constexpr bool test(typename C::const_iterator*) { return true; }
    template<typename C> static constexpr bool test(...) { return false; }
public:
    static constexpr bool value = test<T>(nullptr);
};
```

Now you can use another `static_assert` to check if there's a `const_iterator` for the `Container` explicitly. This step is optional.

Comment: Note that this is not SFINAE friendly.

Comment: Does this also guarantee that the container has a `const_iterator`?

Comment: @philhimself If your using STL containers, yes it'll implicitly check (if there's `cbegin()` and `cend()` which returns `Container::const_iterator`). If your using your own containers, you have to define these.

Answer (score 1):

`hasConstIt` looks redundant here. It can be simplified using the `std::void_t` [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work). You can just write:

```
template <typename Container, typename = std::void_t<typename Container::const_iterator>>
bool contains(/* ... */);
```

If `Container` has `const_iterator` member type, it will be converted into `void` by `std:void_t`, if it doesn't, SFINAE will step in. This is a general technique, but in this particular case you can go further and omit `std::void_t`:

```
template<typename Container, typename = typename Container::const_iterator>
bool contains(/* ... */);
```

To embed an additional constraint on the element type you can just add another dummy template parameter in the standard way:

```
template<typename Container,
         typename = typename Container::const_iterator,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename Container::value_type, int>>>
bool contains(/* ... */);
```