# SFINAE using scope resolution operator in decltype

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

The question [How does `void_t` work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work) shows an example of SFINAE using void_t on a class data member `T::member`. However, it doesn't work if `member` is a function. Why is that the case ? It works if I change the code from `decltype( T::member )` to `decltype( T().member() )`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template< class ... > using void_t = void;

template< class , class = void >
struct has_member : std::false_type
{ };

template< class T >
struct has_member< T , void_t< decltype( T::member ) > > : std::true_type
{ }; 

struct  A {
    void member();
};


int main()
{
    static_assert( has_member< A >::value , "A" ); // assertion fails

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you change it to `decltype(T().member())` you get the decl type of the return value of `member`, don't you?

Comment: `decltype(&T::member)` for method function should work too, `T::non_static_method_function` is invalid.

Comment: `decltype(T().member())` also need default constructible `T`, `decltype(std::declval<T>().member())` is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype( T::member )` doesn't work because `T::member` is not a valid expression expected by [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) when `member` refers to a non-static member function.

You can change it to `decltype( &T::member )` instead. `&T::member` returns pointer to member, it works with both member functions and data members, `static` or non-`static`.

BTW: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3309790)