# enable_if for class template specialization with argument other than void

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, enable-if, class-template

I know that a C++ compiler picks a template specialization in preference to the primary template:

```cpp
template<class T, class Enable = void>
class A {}; // primary template

template<class T>
class A<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, void>> {
}; // specialization for floating point types
```

However, I don't understand why the selection fails when a type other than `void` is used as argument to `enable_if`:

```
template<class T>
class A<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, int>> {
}; // specialization for floating point types
```

The compiler would surely "see" `class A<T, int>`.
So it certainly can't be SFINAE, nevertheless the primary template is preferred to the specialization.

This question arises from a context where a custom type detection machinery could be used instead of `enable_if`, e.g. an SFINAE friendly type extractor like `common_type`.

Comment: Because `int` doesn't match `void`. To be chosen, a specialization has to match the primary template. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work

Comment: I wasn't aware that `void` gets tied to the primary template. Thx for all your great and helpful answers @NathanOliver, @j6t, @463035818_is_not_a_number, @Evg. Well, it's hard to accept a single answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specializations are irrelevant until the compiler knows which types it is going to use for the *primary* template.

When you write `A<double>`, then the compiler looks only at the primary template and sees that you actually mean `A<double,void>`.

And only *then* it is looking for specializations. Now, when your specialization is for `A<double,int>`, then it is not suitable because you asked for `A<double,void>`.

Answer (score 4):

When you have

```
A<some_floating_point_type> some_name;
```

The template parameters are `some_floating_point_type` and the implicit `void`.  When the compiler instantiates

```
template<class T>
class A<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, int>> {
}; // specialization for floating point types
```

it would get `A<some_floating_point_type, int>`, which does not match the `A<some_floating_point_type, void>` type that `some_name` has.  Because of that, the specialization is ignored and you get the primary template.  You can verify this by trying to create a `A<some_floating_point_type, int>` and you'll get that the specialization was picked.

I find it helpful to think of a specialization as an alternate recipe.  First the template arguments are deduced, and then if they match any of the specializations, then we switch to using that alternate recipe.  If not, then the original recipe is used.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, this

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>
class A {};
```

says "A is a template, it has two arguments, the second has a default that is `void`". Thats the primary template. When you explicitly provide only one parameter then the second argument is `void`.

Now the specialization:

```
template<class T>
class A<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, int>> {
};
```

This doesn't change the above. `A` is still a template with 2 arguments and when the second one is not specified then it is `void`. In simple terms it either means "substituting `T` in  `std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>` is a failure, because the type alias does not exist" when the condition is `false`, SFINAE kicks in and the specialization is ignored. When the condition is `true`: "Whenever A is instantiated with arguments T (some type) and `int` then use this definition".

When you instantiate `A<int>` then the second template argument is `void`. The specialization does not change that. That is `A<int>` is actually `A<int,void>`. It does not match the specialiazation.