# Why when use enable_if in class template have to set the second parameter's default type as void?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I'm currently studying `enable_if` and I have this code:

```cpp
//template<typename T, typename = int/double/float/...> //not working properly
template<typename T, typename = void> //works fine
struct test{
    void func(){
        cout << "default" << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct test<T, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(T) <= 1)>::type>{
    void func(){
        cout << "called" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    test<char> objs1;
    objs1.func(); //called
    test<int> objs2;
    objs2.func(); //default
}
```

I don't know the reason why I have to set the second parameter's default value as `void`. If I set it to other values like `int` or `float` or `double`, both `objs1.func();` and `objs2.func();` will print default. What is the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enable\_if for class template specialization with argument other than void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103700/enable-if-for-class-template-specialization-with-argument-other-than-void)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `std::enable_if<...>::type` is, in fact, a type. Because you didn't specify what the type should be, you just specified the condition for which it exists at all, the [default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is `void`.

Let's look at your second version of the template. If `sizeof(T) <= 1`, you provide a template specialization for `test<T, void>`. Otherwise, the substitution fails and you provide nothing.

Now let's consider what happens when you just write `test<char> objs1;`. In your original version, because the default value for the unnamed second template parameter was `void`, this means `objs1` is actually of type `test<char, void>`. And we actually have a specialization for `test<char, void>`, because `sizeof(char) <= 1` is `true`.

However, if you change the default value of the unnamed second template parameter, we get a very different situation. Say you make the default value `int` instead of `void`. Then `test<char> objs1;` is actually declaring an object of type `test<char, int>`. We have a specialization defined for `test<char, void>`... But we aren't trying to create a `test<char, void>`, we're trying to create the separate type `test<char, int>`. So the fact that the condition of the `enable_if` is `true` is neither here nor there and we get the default definition of `test`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a really good explanation.
So I want to double check is:
If I set the defaule value to `int` but do nothing on the `enable_if`，when I call`test<char> objs1;`, it is actually `test<char, int> objs1;`. But for the `enable_if`, although we fulfill the requirement, but because I didn't provide the second parameter for `enable_if`, so it will set it to `void`. At this time, the main template is `<char, int`, but the specialized one is `<char, void>`. So obviously, only the main template is fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Yes. You're creating an object of type `test<char>`, aka `test<char, int>`. The only implementation you have of `test<char, int>` is the default one. If you explicitly create an object of type `test<char, void>`, you'll get the specialized behavior (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4hj5K6aPK)). But if you make it so the default value of the original parameter matches the result type that your `enable_if` yields, it saves you from having to spell out `void` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The technique that is being used is [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) implemented via [partial template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).  In order to have multiple different types of `test`s depending on the characteristics of `T` we need to have the SFINAE expression in the template parameter list.  Since class cannot be overloaded you build an "overload set" by creating a main default template and then partial specializations for all of the different cases.  To do that the main template needs to have two parameters, `T` and the type that `enable_if` will resolve to.  We default that second parameter to `void` so that it does not need to be specified by the caller to get the main template.