# How to access to the actual type of a template specialization type parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose the following structures:

```
// struct 'A'
struct A {
    static std::string toString() { return "A"; }
};
// struct 'B' inherits 'A'
struct B : public A {
    static std::string toString() { return "B"; }
};
// struct 'X'
struct X {
    static std::string toString() { return "X"; }
};
```

then the following template class:

```
template <typename T>  // Common 'ToString' template type:
class ToString {
public:
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Other type: " << T::toString() << "\n";
    }
};
```

and one specialization for `A`:

```
template <>
class ToString<A> {  // Specialization of 'ToString' for type 'A' or subtypes of 'A':
public:
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Subtype of A: " << A::toString() << "\n";
    }
};
```

The result of:

```
int main(void) {
    ToString<X>::print(); // OK: invokes 'template<T> ToString::print()'
    ToString<A>::print(); // OK: invokes 'ToString<A>::print()'
    ToString<B>::print(); // KO: I want it invokes 'ToString<A>::print()'
}
```

is

```
Other type: X
Subtype of A: A
Other type: B
```

I have 2 questions:

1: Since B inherits A, why the output of `ToString<B>::print()` is not something like:

```
Subtype of A: ...
```

2: In `ToString<A>::print()` function, i wrote `... << A::toString() << ...`.
What can I write instead of the (by the way redundant) `A` to refer to the actual type of the template type parameter which is `A` itself or any of its subtypes, so that the output for `B` would be:

```
Subtype of A: B
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specialization for `A` requires an exact match, but `A` and `B` are different types. Inheritance is irrelevant here. Try to make a specialization more generic:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename = std::bool_constant<true>>
struct ToString {
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
struct ToString<T, std::bool_constant<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>>> {
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Subtype of A: " << T::toString() << "\n";
    }
};
```

Now the output is:

```
Other type: X
Subtype of A: A
Subtype of A: B
```

The idea is similar to `std::void_t` trick, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/771noK3eM).

In C++20, you can also do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct ToString {
    // ...
};

template<std::derived_from<A> T>
struct ToString<T> { 
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Subtype of A: " << T::toString() << "\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: The solution using `is_base_of` works for me.
I had to make a modifications though: `is_base_of_v<A, T>` is a non-type argument that uses the template type parameter T so the compiler returns an error. I had to replace it by the type parameter `std::bool_constant<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>`.
Thanks

Comment: @ordellz Interestingly, GCC accepts the code as is, but Clang complains. I've fixed the answer to make Clang happy, too. Thank you for pointing out the error!

Comment: My default ubuntu gcc 9.4 doesn't accept it....
Well, I'm observing gcc accepts it only starting from version 12... (thanks godbolt!)
- Thank you