# Make QtConcurrent::mapped work with lambdas

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am trying to use `QtConcurrent::mapped` into a `QVector<QString>`. I already tried a lot of methods, but it seems there are always problems with overloading.

```
QVector<QString> words = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

using StrDouble = std::pair<QString, double>;

QFuture<StrDouble> result = QtConcurrent::mapped<StrDouble>(words, [](const QString& word) -> StrDouble {
    return std::make_pair(word + word, 10);
});
```

This snippet returns the following error:

```
/home/lhahn/dev/cpp/TestLambdaConcurrent/mainwindow.cpp:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘mapped(QVector<QString>&, MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::<lambda(const QString&)>)’
 });
  ^
```

I saw this [post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/52844/qtconcurrent-map-mapped-without-c-11), which says that Qt cannot find the return value of the lambda, so you have to use `std::bind` with it. If I try this:

```
using StrDouble = std::pair<QString, double>;
using std::placeholders::_1;

auto map_fn = [](const QString& word) -> StrDouble {
    return std::make_pair(word + word, 10.0);
};

auto wrapper_map_fn = std::bind(map_fn, _1);

QFuture<StrDouble> result = QtConcurrent::mapped<StrDouble>(words, wrapper_map_fn);
```

But the the error is still similar:

```
/home/lhahn/dev/cpp/TestLambdaConcurrent/mainwindow.cpp:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘mapped(QVector<QString>&, std::_Bind<MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)::<lambda(const QString&)>(std::_Placeholder<1>)>&)’
 QFuture<StrDouble> result = QtConcurrent::mapped<StrDouble>(words, wrapper_map_fn);
                                                                                  ^
```

I also tried wrapping the lambda inside `std::function` but unfortunately similar results.

- Note that this example is just for reproduction, I need a lambda because I am also capturing variables in my code.

Comment: Apparently, QtConcurrent does not support lambdas yet... As far as I can read from the sources, they want function pointers or member function pointers: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/concurrent/qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h

Answer (score 5):

The following compiles for me:

```
QVector<QString> words = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
std::function<StrDouble(const QString& word)> func = [](const QString &word) {
    return std::make_pair(word + word, 10.0);
};

QFuture<StrDouble> result = QtConcurrent::mapped(words, func);
```

Output of `qDebug() << result.results()`:

> (std::pair("oneone",10), std::pair("twotwo",10), std::pair("threethree",10), std::pair("fourfour",10))

Comment: It works because it have nothing in the capture list. QtConcurrent do not works with lambda function with captures.

Comment: Correct: I mean QtConcurrent::mapped do not works with lambda function with captures

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that QtConcurrent::mapped does not support lambda function with captures. You could need a custom implementation. For example, you may make a one with AsyncFuture:

```
template <typename T, typename Sequence, typename Functor>
QFuture<T> mapped(Sequence input, Functor func){
    auto defer = AsyncFuture::deferred<T>();

    QList<QFuture<T>> futures;
    auto combinator = AsyncFuture::combine();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; i++) {
        auto future = QtConcurrent::run(func, input[i]);
        combinator << future;
        futures << future;
    }

    AsyncFuture::observe(combinator.future()).subscribe([=]() {
        QList<T> res;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < futures.size(); i++) {
            res << futures[i].result();
        }
        auto d = defer;
        d.complete(res);
    });

    return defer.future();
}
```

Usage:

```
auto future = mapped<int>(input, func);
```

Complete Example:

https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture/blob/master/tests/asyncfutureunittests/example.cpp#L326

Answer (score 1):

`QtConcurrent::map[ped]` works with functor types that have the `result_type` member type. Thus you need to wrap the lambda in a class that provides such type. The `std::function` wrapper provides this, but it might have more overhead - thus we can make our own.

Taking code from [How to extract lambda's Return Type and Variadic Parameters Pack back from general template<typename T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43560492/1329652), we have:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> struct function_traits : function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const> {
   // specialization for pointers to member function
   using functor_type = ClassType;
   using result_type = ReturnType;
   using arg_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
   static constexpr auto arity = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <class Callable, class... Args>
struct CallableWrapper : Callable, function_traits<Callable> {
   CallableWrapper(const Callable &f) : Callable(f) {}
   CallableWrapper(Callable &&f) : Callable(std::move(f)) {}
};

template <class F, std::size_t ... Is, class T>
auto wrap_impl(F &&f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, T) {
   return CallableWrapper<F, typename T::result_type,
         std::tuple_element_t<Is, typename T::arg_tuple>...>(std::forward<F>(f));
}

template <class F> auto wrap(F &&f) {
   using traits = function_traits<F>;
   return wrap_impl(std::forward<F>(f),
                    std::make_index_sequence<traits::arity>{}, traits{});
}
```

The wrapped functor, in addition to the `result_type` needed by Qt, also has the `functor_type`, `arg_tuple`, and `arity`.

Instead of passing the lambda directly, pass the wrapped functor:

```
auto result = QtConcurrent::mapped<StrDouble>(words, wrap([](const QString& word){
    return std::make_pair(word + word, 10);
}));
```

The value returned by `wrap` is a functor that implements `result_type`.