# Combine QtConcurrent call

Tags: c++, qt, promise, qt5

I have three methods and all of them returns a string, I want to run all of them using `QtConcurrent` and get their return into a single list or something like that. `QtConcurrent::mapped` is ideal as it returns an iterator but I can only run one method at time.
In JavaScript there's `promise.all([method_a, method_b, method_c])`, it will automatically merge their return into a single result (iterator).
How to do that in Qt?

Comment: Use a QVector and append, if the return is a blocking call. If not `QtConcurrent` is wrong, use QThread and send the value back as a merged single value when all 3 values are available in the thread. There is no syntax to merge all returns in a single value what you would know from Perl or Javascript.

Comment: @user3606329 Of course there is a merge operation, and `QFuture` provides it already via the `results()` method!

Comment: @ Kuba Ober: yes I know about `QFuture::results()`. The OP wanted probably  an one-liner to merge the results of 3 QtConcurrent calls and showed the promise.all method from Javascript as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have several methods to call, you can pass them as a sequence of functors as the first argument to `QtConcurrent::mapped`. The mapping functor would be an `apply` functor that takes a functor representing the method call and returns the result of invoking it.

First, let's have our class:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/concurrent-combine-49802153
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <type_traits>

class Cls {
public:
   QString method1() const { return QStringLiteral("10"); }
   QString method2() const { return QStringLiteral("20"); }
   QString method3() const { return QStringLiteral("30"); }
};
```

The `apply_t` functor invokes the method passed to it as an argument:

```
template <class Method> struct apply_t {
   using result_type = typename std::result_of_t<Method()>;
   auto operator()(Method method) {
      return method();
   }
};
```

Let's make it convenient to make such applicators from the type of a sequence of functors to be called:

```
template <class Sequence, class A = apply_t<typename std::decay_t<Sequence>::value_type>>
A make_apply(Sequence &&) { return {}; }
```

For convenience, we'll also have a vector generator in the spirit of e.g. `make_unique`, etc.:

```
template <class T> QVector<T> make_vector(std::initializer_list<T> init) {
   return {init};
}
```

Then, the problem becomes fairly simple. First, we make a vector of bound methods that will be called. Then we pass the methods to call, as well as the applicator to operate on them, to `QtConcurrent::mapped`. The `results()` gives a list of all results of the method calls, in sequence.

```
int main() {
   Cls obj;
   auto const methods = make_vector({
                                 std::bind(&Cls::method1, &obj),
                                 std::bind(&Cls::method2, &obj),
                                 std::bind(&Cls::method3, &obj)
                              });
   QFuture<QString> result =
         QtConcurrent::mapped(methods, make_apply(methods));
   Q_ASSERT((result.results() == QStringList{"10", "20", "30"}));
}
```

Instead of making a custom `apply_t` class, we could use a lambda, wrapped to provide the `result_type` member type that `QtConcurrent::mapped` expects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821973/1329652) for details of wrapping the lambda. The [rest of this answer](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/concurrent-combine-49802153/main.cpp) provides examples of such wrapping.

Comment: Is `result_type` for? _These function objects can be used to add state to a function call_.，how make of this sentence?

Comment: @Crawl.W `result_type` is the type returned by `Method`. In order to be used in some circumstances, functors (callable objects) need to have a `result_type` type member, or an equivalent type in a trait class.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no built in way to do that, you can work out a class on your own to keep futures together and return a collection of results when all tasks completed. The only limitation, here, is due to the strongly typed nature of c++: each future returned by `QtConcurrent::run` holds the called function result, the type of which is given at compile time, as the `QFuture` template parameter. What if the return types of the called functions differ from each other? In the example I provide, they all return the same type, but I think one could use `QVariant` for that mean and get away with it.

In a *promise.h*:

```
#ifndef PROMISE_H
#define PROMISE_H

#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QFutureWatcher>

class PromiseInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~PromiseInterface() = default;
    virtual void finished(int id) = 0;
};

class Watcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int _id;
    PromiseInterface * _promise;

public slots:
    void finished()
    {
       _promise->finished(_id);
       deleteLater();
    }

public:
    Watcher(int id, PromiseInterface * promise)
        : _id(id),
          _promise(promise)
    {}
};

template <typename T>
class Promise : public PromiseInterface
{
    friend class Watcher;
    void finished(int id) override
    {
        _resolved++;
        _results[id] = _watchers[id]->result();
        delete _watchers[id];

        if(_resolved == _results.size())
        {
            if(_callback != nullptr)
            {
                _callback(_results);
            }
        }
    }
    QList<QFutureWatcher<T> *> _watchers;
    QVector<T> _results;
    void (*_callback)(QVector<T>);
    int _resolved;
public:
    Promise(QList<QFuture<T>> futures)
    {
        _resolved = 0;
        _callback = nullptr;
        _results.resize(futures.size());

        int i=0;
        for(auto f : futures)
        {
            QFutureWatcher<T> * watcher = new QFutureWatcher<T>();
            watcher->setFuture(f);
            QObject::connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<T>::finished, new Watcher(i++, this), &Watcher::finished);
            _watchers.append(watcher);
        }
    }
    void then(void (*callback)(QVector<T>)) { _callback = callback; }
};

#endif // PROMISE_H
```

The `Promise` class is a class template with a single template parameter that matches the one of `QFuture`. The observed futures are passed in the constructor, while the `then` method accepts a the completion callback as its only argument.

The `Watcher` class provides a slot to catch `QFutureWatcher::finished' signals. Each instance knows the promise object through a pointer to its`PromiseInterface`and will call`finished` from the slot, passing in the id of the future that completed.

When all futures finished, the callback function is called with the vector of results passed in.

In a very simple usage example, we can execute this function concurrently:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int f(int r) { sleep(1); return r;}
```

and pass this callback to the promise `then`:

```
void callback(QVector<int> results)
{
    qDebug() << results;
}
```

Our main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QList<QFuture<int>> futures = {
        QtConcurrent::run(&f, 1),
        QtConcurrent::run(&f, 2),
        QtConcurrent::run(&f, 3)
    };

    Promise<int> promise(futures);
    promise.then(callback);

    return a.exec();
}
```

After about a second, this is the expected output:

```
QVector(1, 2, 3)
```

Just in case one wonders why I put in three classes, instead of making `Promise` extend `QObject` directly, and implement the `finished` slot itself: Qt is not letting me do that. When the `Q_OBJECT` macro is added to a class template, an explicit compiler error will prompt: *Template classes not supported by Q_OBJECT*.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is [`QFuture::results()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#results):

> **`QList<T> QFuture::results() const`**
>
> Returns all results from the future. If the results are not
>   immediately available, this function will block and wait for them to
>   become available.

Expanding from Qt's own [`QtConcurrent::mapped` example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html):

```
QImage scaled(const QImage &image)
{
   return image.scaled(100, 100);
}

QList<QImage> images = ...;
QList<QImage> thumbnails = QtConcurrent::mapped(images, scaled).results();
```

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant, I want to call three methods at the same time, imagine that there's `scaled1`, `scaled2`, `scaled3` and not only `scaled`. and get the result of all of them like the `promise.all` from javascript.

Comment: @MrGisa get them one by one and concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

I know [`AsyncFuture`](https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture) is a c++ library that converts calls into a QFuture type and uses it like a Promise object in Javascript (*Combine multiple futures with different type into a single future object*). unfortunately i never used it! but there are details on this reference Qt Blog [Multithreaded Programming with Future & Promise](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/04/18/multithreaded-programming-future-promise/)